# Logical shift right operation on signed integer

Tags: bit-shift

Logical shift right by 3 operation on signed integer -28. What's the correct answer?

1. +203
2. +83
3. +3
4. -3

2's complement of -28 is 11100100.
Now if I apply logical right shift operation I am not getting any one of above answers.

Comment: Did you try writing and compiling the code to see? Since I'm not interviewing with you, I think I'll pass on answering.

Comment: Yes i tried executing this in java by using >>> , i got very big number(536870908).

Comment: @Jagan Got same result in C using `(signed int)((unsigned int)-28>>3)`.  If you think about it, getting a very large positive # makes sense because you are making the 1 that used to be the sign bit into the 3rd most significant bit of the magnitude.

Comment: Also, the answer depends on how many bytes represent an int.  I'm assuming 4, but it's an important part of the question.

Comment: @Jon Rodriguez:What's the correct answer among 4 options and how ?

Comment: @Jon Rodriguez:I am not getting the answer despite assuming 2 or 3 or 4 bytes for integer.

Comment: @Jagan And 1 byte won't make it work either.  As I state in my answer below, it's a trick question.

Comment: Note: this result doesn't hold true for all languages. C# will give you something different, for example.

Comment: OK, the "logical" vs "arithmetical" shift distinction isn't in high-level languages as far as I'm avare, it is a machine instruction distinction. And "logical shift" means what e.g. C does to an unsigned quantity (just shift the bits, fill with zeros). So it maters how -3 is represented, and the number of bits in the quantity manipulated.

Comment: I cannot get any of the above answers for a logical right shift of 3. The best i get is 28. Assuming an 8 bit signed number. Drat, i thought i understood bit shifting. i do.

Comment: (Really) late comment (for late readers): No matter how many *bits* the representation uses – none of the numbers offered *can* be the right one for a pretty simple reason: All of these are *odd*, but the result – even if negative due to infinite(!) leading one-bits – is, note the trailing zero, *even* ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost certain it's a trick question.

The interviewer was seeing if you would answer "-3".  If you would have (with the faulty reasoning that since 28>>>3 is 3 then -28>>>3 is -3), he would have realized that you don't understand two's complement.

He wanted you to answer that none of the four choices is correct.  He wanted you to

1. explain how logical shift right,
   unlike arithmetic shift right, would
   turn a small neg number into a huge
   positive number by turning the sign
   bit into part of the magnitude
2. point out that the answer depends on
   how many bytes are used to represent
   an int

Comment: But this is written-test question i don't have other options :-)

Comment: If it's a written test that you are in the process of taking, you are not allowed to post it here and I can't help you.

Comment: @Jon Rodriguez: I am not in examination room writing online exam.I am about take the exam after 1 or 2 months. Then what is wrong in knowing things that i don't know ?

Comment: @Jagan: point out the error to the proctor. Get brownie points.

Comment: @Jagan: assuming that none of the multiple-choice answers are correct, you might get recognition by pointing out the error to the folks running the test.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta:This was the written test conducted by one of the reputed IT companies in this world for recruitment process.

Comment: @Jagan: we all make mistakes.

Comment: I am sorry i was wrong, I wouldn't like to think it a trick question, however, it certainly isn't as clear as it should be as a 'teaching exercise'. I have failed it. ;-/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the trick is not to assume two's complement representation.  Assuming [sign-and-magnitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Sign-and-magnitude_method) representation, the answer can be -3, since most shifting implementations would not involve the sign bit.

Answer (score 0):

It's a stupid question as:

- whether a 0 or a 1 is added at the left isn't universally defined for negative numbers (Wikipedia says "vacant bit-positions are filled in, *generally* with zeros" - my emphasis)
- the integer size involved isn't discussed, and
- there are multiple bitwise representations of negative numbers in use.

Some languages (like Java I believe) the new most-significant bits such that any platform that doesn't have a suitable CPU instruction will have to issue several to calculate the required answer, whereas other languages may make an implementation-defined choise between the behaviours the CPU natively offers.

2's complement is the most common representation of negative numbers.  Your question states "2's complement of -28 is 11100100."... I'm guessing that wasn't provided as part of the question (a bit weird if so, as it's after the answers). Still...

If we run with 2's complement...

```
11100100 >> 3 = 00011100 or 11111100 = 28 or -4
```

If the representation was 1's complement:

```
11100011 >> 3 = 00011100 or 11111100 = 28 or -3
```

If the representation was sign-bit, absolute-value:

```
10011100 >> 3 = 00010011 or 11110011 = 19 or -(127-12)=-115

(note that the question says a logical bit shift, which by definition ignores any possible interpretation of the bits, so the sign bit is shifted along with others)
```

Re #bits in an int... I think it's so obvious that that would either result in a value that's too large to match any of the options, or else it wouldn't make any difference (if 1s are being added at left for a 1's or 2's complement), that we can ignore that issue.

So, unless my quick calculation above slipped up, -3 is the only answer that could be correct on any plausible architecture, but is still very unlikely.  All up, I'm wondering if they weren't actually testing to see who had the confidence to leave the question unanswered, or annotate that none of the answers were likely correct....

Answer (score 0):

Shifting a signed integer to the right can do a number of things:

1. if the number was negative, it'll sign extend the result (shifts in 1 bits on the left side), which should have the effect of making the number look like a smaller negative number.
2. If the number was positive, it'll divide it by two for each bit you shifted.

But this behavior is technically "implementation defined."

Please see this post: [Are the shift operators (<<, >>) arithmetic or logical in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622/shift-operator-in-c)