# Swapping 2 variables from a matrix in C

Tags: c

So I have to make a program that can determinate the maximum from the diagonal of a matrix. Than I have to swap it's place of the first variable of the matrix (a[1][1]) with the maximum of that matrix, the other elements beeing unchanged.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int a[20][20];
int main(){
    int i, j, n1, n2, max;
    printf ("\nIntroduceti numarul de coloane pentru matricea A: ");
    scanf (" %d", &n2);
    printf ("\nIntroduceti numarul de randuri pentru matricea A: ");
    scanf (" %d", &n1);
    printf("\nIntroduceti elementele primei matrice: ");
    for(i=1;i<=n1;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=n2;j++){
            printf("\na[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\nMatricea A este:\n");
    for(i=1;i<=n1;i++){
        printf("\n");
        for(j=1;j<=n2;j++){
            printf("%d\t",a[i][j]);
        }
    }


    do {
        for(i=1;i<=n1;i++){
            if(a[i][i]>max) {
                max=a[i][i];
            }
        }
    } while (i<=n1);
    printf ("\nMaximul de pe diagonala este: %d", max);

    a[1][1]=a[1][1]^max;
    max=max^a[1][1];
    a[1][1]=max^a[1][1];

        for(i=1;i<=n1;i++){
        printf("\n");
        for(j=1;j<=n2;j++){
            printf("%d\t",a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What I did wrong? My program swaps only the maximum with the first variable a[1][1], but forgets to place a[1][1] where the maximum is.

Comment: The logic behind your swapping doesn't seem wrong - therefore the title isn't even relevant.

Comment: In C, array indices start with 0!

Comment: @ZachP Well, the logic is good, but it doesn't do what i need it to do. My program swaps only the maximum with the first variable a[1][1], but forgets to place a[1][1] where the maximum is. Why?

Comment: @NeacsuMihai [Take a look here](http://ideone.com/CrKFJc), maybe helps.

Comment: Why are you using XOR swap? It's more confusing to read and probably won't give you any significant performance gain with a modern compiler. (See [Why don't people use xor swaps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16535461/why-dont-people-use-xor-swaps).)

Comment: Add a variable to save the i when you save the max, then `a[max_i][max_i] = a[1][1]; a[1][1] = max;`

Comment: @e0k I've tried using a 3rd variable too, but I got the same problem, that i get using XOR swap too..

Comment: @NeacsuMihai Youd do not really need [a 3rd variable](http://ideone.com/t1UgtP).

Comment: Wouldn't you need to keep track of both the maximum _value_ and the _index_ where the maximum value is located? Otherwise, how could you swap elements in the matrix without knowing _where_ the maximum is (in addition to _what_ it is)?

Comment: @e0k Yes, I have to track both of those things, but I don't know how to programm it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You iterate completely through the diagonal elements, keeping track of only the maximum *value*, then (after the loop) you try to swap this value with the first element of the matrix. The problem is that you no longer know *where* the maximum value was, since you never recorded that! You just record *what* the value was (in `max`), and ignored its *index* in the matrix.

For example, suppose your maximum value happens to be at `a[2][2]`. You iterate through the diagonal elements, find the maximum *value*, store it in `max`. At the end of your loop, you can't swap `a[2][2]` with `a[0][0]` because you lost the information that the maximum is at `a[2][2]`. (Assuming you learned the issue about array indexes starting at 0.) What you are doing is writing `max` to the first element `a[0][0]`. `a[2][2]` is unchanged because you don't change it, and you forgot where it was to change it anyway.

You need to keep track of the maximum *value* in some variable (`max` as it is written now is fine) and add another variable (say, `max_pos` for example) to keep track of the *index* of where this maximum value is. (You only need one `int` because they're diagonal elements, so both array indexes are always the same.) Any time you change the maximum value `max`, also update the maximum position `max_pos`. This way you would know at the end to swap `a[0][0]` and `a[max_pos][max_pos]`.

---

A brief sketch of what the code might look like (I'll leave it you to fill in any details):

Add a declaration of a new variable to keep track of the *position* (say, `max_pos`) of the maximum value:

```
int i, j, n1, n2, max, max_pos;
```

You need to initialize `max` and `max_pos` with the first diagonal element, then iterate through the others.

```
max = a[0][0];
max_pos = 0;
for (i=0; i<n1; i++){
    if (a[i][i] > max) {
        max = a[i][i];
        max_pos = i;    // update max_pos anytime max is updated
    }
}
```

Notice how I changed the range of the indexes from 1...*n1* to 0..*n1*-1. (Make this consistent with the rest of your code.) Array indexes in C start with 0, not with 1. Notice here that you don't need that `do {} while ()` loop. Think about what it is really doing (hint: nothing).

Then, after this, you can swap `a[0][0]` and `a[max_pos][max_pos]`. By the way, [XOR swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16535461/why-dont-people-use-xor-swaps) is not necessary and makes the code harder to read. Just swap values with a temporary variable. Modern compilers are very good at optimizing and can likely implement this with registers, so you're probably not gaining whatever efficiency you think you are (and you're only doing it once). Don't try to outsmart your compiler.

Answer (score 1):

**Suggestion for cleanup**

When you have

```
int a[20][20];
```

The valid range of elements are `a[0][0]` - `a[19][19]`.

You are accessing elements `a[1][1]` - `a[n1][n2]` in all the `for` loops since you are using:

```
for(i=1;i<=n1;i++){
    for(j=1;j<=n2;j++){
```

That won't be a problem unless the value of `n1` or the value of `n2` is 20.

Change those loops to use:

```
for(i=0; i < n1; i++){
    for(j=0; j < n2; j++){
```

**Main problem**

The main problem in your code is that you are using `max` before it's initialized. Add a line to initialize `max` to `a[0][0]` before the loop to compute its final value.

```
// Remove the `do-while` part. You don't need it.
max = a[0][0];
for(i=0; i < n1; i++){
    if(a[i][i]>max) {
        max=a[i][i];
    }
}
```

Comment: I did the things you told me, but I encounter the same problem maximum goes into a[0][0] place, but a[0][0] don't go in the place where maximum is..

Comment: @NeacsuMihai, you don't have any code for doing that. You are only swapping the values of `max` and `a[0][0]`. You are not swapping any other values.

Comment: Man... I get it that I am not swapping any other values than max and a[0][0]; If I run this program I will get a matrix where only a[0][0] is changed... I don't know how to explain it more clearly, try to run it... Example, my maximum is where a[2][2] is, so it should swap the value of a[2][2] with a[0][0], well.. This is false because my program only puts the value of a[2][2] over a[0][0], so it does not swap them.. Now you understand what is my problem....?