# Bitwise operators : why is ~35=-36?

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

so here is my code :
The aNSWER is -36

is -36 written as sign bit notation ?
i cant understand the bitwise conversion giong on, in using Dev c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
printf("%d",~35);
getch();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644362/bitwise-operation-on-signed-integer

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement

Answer (score -2):

Most significant bit determines if the number is negative or positive.

Comment: (Not the downvoter) Well, yes, but not in the way you are insinuating here.

Comment: This answer is really more confusing than it is helpful