# Bitwise Rightshift Assignment operation in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, machine-code, binary-operators

The output to this Leftshift assignment operator is -8.I didn't understand how.Please help!

```
#include < stdio.h>

int main()
{    
    int y = -1;

    y <<= 3; 
    printf("%d", y);// prints -8;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you recompiled after you changed it from left shift to right shift?

Comment: Change the printf to `printf("hello %d\n", y);` and try again.

Comment: Right shifting negative numbers is *implementation defined*. On the systems using the common 2's complement representation, it's  equivalent to arithmetic shift and your program will print `-1`. If it's really printing `-8`, you should update the Q with your system details.

Comment: Thankyou all ; I had forgotten to convert 2's complement back to decimal.

Answer (score 2):

In a 32-bit 2's-complement signed integer, the hexadecimal and binary representations of these numbers are:

```
-1 = 0xffffffff = 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
-8 = 0xfffffff8 = 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111000
```

The second of which is clearly the first left-shifted by three bits, with the three extra 1s "falling off" the left side, and the three bits on the right being filled with zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

Valid question. The answer lies in shift-wise operators behaves differently for negative values. Especially for leftshift assignments.

You can go through these 2 links to clear your doubts.

[Bitwise operation on signed integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644362/bitwise-operation-on-signed-integer)

and

[Shift operator in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622/shift-operator-in-c)

Hope it helps.Thanks.