# Will repeated ~ and << operations converge to a negative value on all platforms?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

In the following program, will repeated ~ and << operations converge to a negative value on all platforms?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x{};
    for(int i{}; i < 32; ++i) {
        x = ~x;
        x <<= 1;
        std::cout << x << '\n';
    }
}
```

My assessment is that it will because the left shift is not implementation defined. Would it be true to say that the only time it will not converge is if `int` is larger than 32 bits?

Comment: What is `int i{}` supposed to mean? Or `int x{}` for that matter? An empty initializer list for an ordinal, vs `=0`, which is the default for that datatype, anyway?

Comment: Left shift of signed variables is undefined if it overflows.

Comment: @DavidLively `int i{}` means value initialization. For a POD integer this means it will be initialized to 0.

Comment: @Barmar Good point. But does it overflow in this case?

Comment: `int`s are default-initialized to 0, and in 30 years of development this is the only time I've seen anyone use a `{}` on an ordinal type. Also, `{}` basically means "default initializer" MOST of the time, so it's useless. Thus concludes my rant.

Comment: @DavidLively - You'd prefer `int i = 0`?

Comment: @Robᵩ I'd prefer it just be left off, but `int i = 0` is a lot more readable. But, I didn't mean to start an argument in the comments. Cheers.

Comment: @DavidLively the empty braces are [not an initializer list in this case](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). Only if the type has no default constructor but has a constructor taking std::initializer_list will it perform list initialization. I truly want to avoid obfuscated code. For me this style has developed from consistent use of brace initialization wherever possible. Declared variables without an initializer become easier to see.

Comment: @Robᵩ Which answer are you referring to? I see **Otherwise, if E1 has a signed type and non-negative value, and E1×2E^2 is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.** This question is creating a negative value when it does `~x`, then it shifts it. Shifting a negative is undefined.

Comment: @Muscampester - yes, it overflows in the first iteration. `x = ~0; x<<=1;` overflows.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644362/are-the-results-of-bitwise-operations-on-signed-integers-defined

Comment: @Barmar - I misread that answer.

Comment: @Barmar Undefined behavior it is then. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @David Lively `int i{}` is the sort of new stupidities that arrived with c++11, making the language ever more of a mess than it was already.

Answer (score 0):

> My assessment is that it will because the left shift is not
>   implementation defined.

The above statement is wrong. Left shift of a negative value is [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3785121/1460794) and the value is negative as soon as the bits of the initial zero value are inverted.

---

If the variable had been an unsigned integer then it would be fair to say that it will converge to a positive value on all compliant platforms (if enough of the bits are shifted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    unsigned short x{};
    for(int i{}; i < CHAR_BIT*sizeof(unsigned short); ++i) {
        x = ~x;
        x <<= 1;
        std::cout << x << '\n';
    }
}
```

Produces (on a 2's complement system):

```
65534
2
65530
10
65514
42
65450
170
65194
682
64170
2730
60074
10922
43690
43690
```

Comment: test on one/some/most platform cannot be evidence for ALL platforms

Comment: to be true, real modern platforms usually are more common in arithmetic than ancient. I can conditionally agree with practice assumptions on 99% today architectures. But aren't portable in general.

Comment: @JacekCz Good point. Only if the platforms are c++ standards compliant.

Comment: Your "produces" would be different on non 2's complement

Comment: @M.M Hmm. Didn't consider that. So it would still converge, but just to a different value?

Comment: I think you meant "If the variable had been an unsigned integer"

Comment: @JordanMelo :) Yes that's what I meant.