# Why might signed overflow occur when changing division to right-shift?

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, integer-overflow, gcc-warning

When optimising, GCC sometimes tells me

> assuming signed overflow does not occur when simplifying `/` or `%` to `>>` or `&`
>   [`-Wstrict-overflow`]

I failed to make a reproducible test-case for this, but my production code contains something like

```
int left = a.left() + (a.width() - b.width()) / 2;
```

where all the methods return `int` values.

Why might the compiler's replacement of `/2` with `>>1` or (e.g.) `%4` with `&3` lead to integer overflow?

Comment: >> on signed integers is implementation-dependent. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644362/are-the-results-of-bitwise-operations-on-signed-integers-defined

Comment: I think I misunderstood the warning to mean that the result might be **undefined**.  But it's just telling us that it's **implementation-defined**.  Which isn't quite so bad - but still useful to be warned about.

Comment: Note that this is different to a *programmer* substituting `/` with `>>` for example, as the compiler should know what it's targeting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arithmetic bit-shift on a signed integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009885/arithmetic-bit-shift-on-a-signed-integer)

Comment: @Jay-Pi: not really, because the compiler should be using an arithmetic (sign-preserving) shift for this optimisation, otherwise it's not equivalent.  Perhaps the warning is emitted when arithmetic shift isn't available?

Answer (score 2):

Shifting a new bit into the sign bit causes unexpected results to happen:
1001 (signed decimal: 7) >> 1 results in:
0100 (signed decimal: 4).
At least with implementations using two's complement, which is the majority.

Edit: On x86, though, there are shift instructions which preserve the sign bit.

Comment: Last time I checked, binary 1001 was decimal 9, and 9/2==4.  Given that the compiler knows that the arguments are (signed) integers,  I'd expect it to either (a) use (or emulate) signed right-shift, or (b) skip this simplification if it knows it's unreasonable.

Comment: This is correct for C and C++17, but does not answer the question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4009954/9306292 as the language semantics answers the question.

For example C++20 has different behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56025569/9306292