# Can someone help me to understand output of this code

Tags: c

Hello beautiful people, 
I need a help with output of this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x,y;
    scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
    int t = x^y;
    int p = 0;
    while (t > 0) {
        p += t%2;
        t /= 2;
    }
    printf("%d", p);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to write it down on paper and do some work by hand.
So i wrote this :

lets say for x = 2 and y = 4

1. first iteration:

   p = 0 + 16mod2 which is equal to 0

   t = 8
2. second iteration:

   p = 0 + 8mod2 which is equal to 0

   t = 4
3. third iteration:

   p = 0 + 4mod2 which is equal to 0

   t = 2
4. forth iteration:

   p = 0 + 2mod2 which is equal to 0

   t = 1

And output should be 0, but somehow when I run code I get 2. 
Can someone help me out with this one please? And are there any other cases to consider, like what if x = 0, y = 0 or x and y are < 0 ?

Comment: Hamming distance?

Comment: @EOF it is indeed hamming distance

Comment: `x^y` is an exclusive OR on x and y, not x to the power of y.

Comment: Bit operations are technically only defined for `unsigned` types. Better to use an exact unsigned type, e.g. `#include <stdint.h>` and then `uint32_t` instead of `int`, or at least `unsigned` instead of `int`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin From where do you get bit operations only being defined for unsigned types? They *might* only be defined for *non-negative* **values**, but that is not the same at all.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Can you please provide a reference to the standard supporting your statement?

Comment: [**Are the results of bitwise operations on signed integers defined?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644362/are-the-results-of-bitwise-operations-on-signed-integers-defined)

Comment: OK, the artful explanation is `non-negative` instead of `unsigned` point well taken. (I guess that begs the question -- *"How to easily protect against non-negative entry from a type-safety standpoint?*").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here, is that you assume that `2^4 == 16`, when in fact, it is only `6`, as the `^` operator, is actually an `XOR`.

You should be using

```
int t = pow(x, y)
```

Comment: use pow(x,y) instead

Comment: Simple mistake for somebody learning, as the carrot generally represents exponents in math ;) Be sure to include `math.h` to have access to this method. Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
 int t = x^y;
```

Is not "`x` raised to the power of `y`".  It's "`x` XOR `y`".  T starts at 6 in your example.

Comment: `t` is not always 0. `2^4` is 6. 100b XOR 010b = 110b = 6d

Comment: I caught it just as you were commenting.  I was thinking of AND.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned x^y is `XOR` operation, what you had in mind is :

```
#include <math.h>
....
int t = pow(x,y);
```