# CLion Clang-Tidy use of a signed integer operand with a binary bitwise operator

Tags: c, clion

I am getting warning in my c file when I try to use >> operand.Anyone who can tell me what does it mean?

[code]:

```
 new_elem = (Elem *) realloc(pl->elem, (pl->size + (pl->size >> 1)) * sizeof(Elem));
```

[warning]:

```
Clang-Tidy use of a signed integer operand with a binary bitwise operator.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are the results of bitwise operations on signed integers defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644362/are-the-results-of-bitwise-operations-on-signed-integers-defined)

Comment: The question for me is why do you do it? A division by 2 would be nicer there to my mind. And If `pl->size == 1` I am not sure you get what you want.

Comment: In c, you should avoid cast pointer explicitly in malloc/realloc

Comment: tl;dr: You used `int` for pl->size but you should have used `size_t` instead.

Comment: @陳力 I got it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

In C, if a variable is a signed integer, then the binary bitwise operator `>>` on it is implementation dependent (you shouldn't rely on it). See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644362/are-the-results-of-bitwise-operations-on-signed-integers-defined) as Gaurav suggested in comments.
In your exmaple, `pl->size` is (guessing!) a signed integer, and you do `(pl->size >> 1)`, so you apply a binary bitwise operator `>>` on `pl->size` variable. Clang tries to warn you about an implementation defined behavior, so you can fix your code.
Use division and multiplication on signed integers, which is well defined. The compiler should optimize the code anyway.

```
new_elem = realloc(pl->elem, (pl->size + (pl->size/2)) * sizeof(Elem));
```