# Not equal using bitwise operations?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I'll be forthright about this: this one *is* for homework. However, as I've already completed the question and was just simply curious about different implementations of what I did, I thought it was okay to be consult y'all.

The question was to build a `!=` function using bitwise operations. We are also allowed to use `!` and `+`.

Returns `0` if `x==y`, otherwise it returns `1`.

```
int eval_not_equal(int x, int y) {
    int result = x ^ y;
    if(result == 0) {
        result = 0;
    }
    else {
       result = 1; 
     }
    return result;
}
```

I think this is a perfectly fine answer to the question, but I was wondering if it's possible to do this without using an `if`? There are quite a few different bitwise operations, and I'm sure there's gotta be a way to use them in order to replace the `if` that I used!

Would love to know what you guys think! :-)

Comment: Note that this approach only works when your implementation uses two's complement to represent integers (which is admittedly the norm these days). Ref. [Are the results of bitwise operations on signed integers defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644362/are-the-results-of-bitwise-operations-on-signed-integers-defined)

Comment: I think, this cannot be done without using other operations than bit operations (either implicitly or explicitly). A comparison is not a bit-operation (`==`), logical not (`!`)  is not a bit operation and constructs like `if (x ^ y)` are also logical operations. The function `ffs()` used below is no c primitive and its implementation also has to use logical operations.

Comment: Since any non-zero result is treated as "true" in C, the `if` should be dropped and you simply return `x^y` directly (since you aren't allowed `!=`, you almost certainly also aren't allowed to use `==` either because then you don't need any bitwise operations at all). That you are allowed to use `+` as well is simply a red herring.

Answer (score 4):

I do not understand why you cannot use `operator !=`:

```c
int eval_not_equal(int x, int y) {
    return x != y;
}
```

but if that is some kind of challenge to avoid `!=` in the code, then you can write like this:

```c
int eval_not_equal(int x, int y) {
    return !!(x ^ y);
}
```

In the code above, the result of `x ^ y` is treated as bool, then negated. The boolean equivalent of "false" is 0; "true" by default is 1 (but actually any non-zero integer is true)

If this is C++, or usage of stdbool is permitted (C99), then you can do also like this:

```c
int eval_not_equal(int x, int y) {
    return (bool) (x ^ y);
}
```

### Update:

> The question was to build a != function using ***only*** bitwise operations

If "only" is the key, then neither mine previous answers nor OP's solution are valid because `!` is a *boolean* operator not bitwise. The same applies to type cast `(bool)` or `if` clause.

In my honest opinion, the following code is ridiculous, but it uses only bitwise operations:

```c
int eval_not_equal(int x, int y) {
    int xo = (x ^ y);
    return (xo >> (ffs(xo) - 1)) & 1;
}
```

Function `ffs()` returns first set bit, i.e. the index of the first bit which equals to 1. We want only that bit, so we shift right the xor result by `ffs - 1` to get rid of all lower bits, then do bitwise-and-with-1 to clear higher bits.

Comment: Why use the double negation when using the bitwise XOR? The double negation just removes the first negation which makes it completely obsolete.

(0 ^ 0 = 0),
(0 ^ 1 = 1),
(1 ^ 0 = 1),
(1 ^ 1 = 0)

Comment: Probably the reason why the OP wants this is some manner of pre-mature optimization. Many architectures will translate `!=` into XOR in the machine code. But the compiler is perfectly capable of doing that optimization. That being said, the function call overhead is what takes time here.

Comment: @Pethead Because XOR is already similar to "not equal", except in case of non-zero results, it can have any value. Whereas `!=` returns exactly `1`, similar to boolean. The double !! turns the non-zero into zero and then turns that into the number `1`.

Comment: @Pethead : `1 ^ 2 == 3`, `!(1 ^ 2) == 0`, `!!(1 ^ 2) == 1`

Comment: @Pethead Usage of `!!` is common practice to map any non-zero value to `true`.

Comment: To add for understanding why you wouldn't be able to use `!=`, I'm working with a logic-module in building automation, and it cannot use "not equal" for bit-fields, but it certainly has all the bitwise operators (which makes sense, since `XOR` and `NOT` can do "not equal" and "equal"). So that limitation does exist in real life ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use **double negation** and a series of `XOR`'s to accomplish this like this. This also works for negative numbers.

- `i32` is just a `32bit signed int`

```
inline i32 negate(i32 x){ return ((x >> 31) | ((~x + 1) >> 31)) + 1; }
inline i32 ne(i32 a, i32 b){ return negate(a ^ b) ^ 1; }

int main(){
    printf("result=%i\n", ne(-1, -1)); // 0
    printf("result=%i\n", ne(-5, 0));  // 1
    printf("result=%i\n", ne(0, 0));   // 0
    printf("result=%i\n", ne(5, 5));   // 0
    printf("result=%i\n", ne(1, 5));   // 1
    printf("result=%i\n", ne(5, 1));   // 1
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could just do the following:

```
return !(x ^ y);
```

Comment: That doesn't return `1` if they're not equal.

Comment: You probably want double negation ;)