# how to determine if a 0 bit in one int goes to 1 in another int

Tags: c, int, bitwise-operators, bit

Say you have two integers, A and B.

```
int A = 0b0011;
int B = 0b1001;
```

How do I determine if a `0` in A goes to a `1` in B.

I don't care if a `1` in A goes to `0` in B, or if the bit stays the same, only if a `0` goes to a `1`.

The output I would want here would be:

```
result = 0b1000
```

Comment: You need to calculate bitwise `~A & B`.

Comment: Note that you ought to be using unsigned types for your bitwise operations; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644362/are-the-results-of-bitwise-operations-on-signed-integers-defined

Answer (score 2):

A xor B

```
0011
1001
----
1010
```

Result & B

```
1010
1001
----
1000
```

Xor sets to 1 bits that are different in A and B. But you are only interested in cases where 0' in A is 1' in B. To turn off such bits, simply & with B.