# what left and right shift operator and how they works

Tags: c#-4.0

//((Hello everybody!
i am C# beginner  can any one tell me the function of left and right shift operator and their working way w.r.t the following program. I read it somewhere but  confuse.
thanks ))

```
using System;
class clc
{
    public static void Main() // the Main method
    {
        int x = 7, y = 2, z, r;
        z = x << y ; //left shift operator
        r = x >> y; // right shift operator
        Console.WriteLine("\n z={3}\tr={4} ",z,r);

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you take a look at [C# Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/6a71f45d.aspx) on MSDN? What there did you not understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand the shift operations you must understand binary numbers.

Let's take your example for left shift:

```
z = 7 << 2;
```

32 bit integer **7** is **0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0111** in binary. You must move the bits to the left beginning from the right. The bits that are shifted out of either end are discarded.

Shifting it by 1 will result **0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1110**

Shifting it by 1 one more time will result **0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 1100** which is 28 in integer representation.

Read this good wikipedia article [Binary number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift)

Comment: what about the sign  integers?

Comment: @user2083069 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009885/arithmetic-bit-shift-on-a-signed-integer