# bitwise macro for getting a bit not working

Tags: c, macros

I have a short variable (16 bits) and an index (unsigned char).
I need a macro that returns the `index`th in my variable `data`.
This is what I got:

```
#define GETBIT(data, index) data & 1 << index
```

And how I use it:

```
unsigned char i;
short * twobytes = (short *) calloc(1, sizeof(short));
twobytes =  ((char * )buffer + *currentIndex);
while (codeLength != 0)
{
    i = GETBIT(code, codeLength--);
    *twobytes = SETBIT(*twobytes, *currentBitIndex, i);
    (*currentBitIndex)++;
    if (*currentBitIndex == 8) {
        (*currentIndex)++;
        (*currentBitIndex) %= 8;
    }
}
```

For some reason `i` always equals to `0` in my test cases, where it sometimes should equal `1`.

What am I doing wrong and how should I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of `code`?

Comment: `#define GETBIT(data, index) data & (1 << index)`

Comment: In the first case `00` and in the second one `01`, in both cases I get just zeroes.

Comment: @dari Still no difference.

Comment: You're not reading the rightmost bit.

Comment: @dari: `<<` has higher precedence than `&`. shoham: `01 & 1 << 1` is `01 & 2` which is `0` and `codeLength` is never `0` when you use `GETBIT`.

Comment: Also, always put parenthesis around macros (if they evaluate to a value) and around the arguments: `#define GETBIT(data, index) ((data) & 1<<(index))`.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, thanks, instead of `codeLength--` I should've done `--codeLength`.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
$ cat qq.c 
#include <stdio.h>

#define GETBIT(data, index) ((data & (1 << index)) == 0 ? 0 : 1)

int main() {
    const int x = 14;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        printf("%d ", GETBIT(x, i));
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Run:

```
$ gcc -Wall qq.c && ./a.out 
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: `#define GETBIT(data, index) (((uintmax_t)(data) >> (index)) & 1)` is a little more general and a little simpler.  If you are sure that the `data` is never any larger than `int`, then `unsigned` instead of `uintmax_t`.  It's generally worth avoiding shifts of signed values !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4009954/2557000 (excerpt 6.5.7/4). But, of course, bitwise operations require to be very careful :)