# Weird behavior of & operator in C

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

As part of a puzzle I am asked to implement a function which checks if two ints can be added together without overflow. Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>.

For example for x = 0x80000000 and y = 0x80000000 the function should return 0 since it is overflowing but for x = 0x80000000 and y = 0x70000000 the result would be 1.

My solution so far is:

```
int addOK(int x, int y) {
    int mask = ~(1 << 31);        // 0x7fffffff
    int newX = (mask & (x >> 1)); // Shift 1 to the right to make space for overflow bit
    int newY = (mask & (y >> 1));
    int add = newX + newY;        // Add shifted x and y - overflow bit will be the MSB
    int res = (add & ~mask);      // Set all bits to 0 except MSB - MSB 1 iff overflow 0 otherwise
    int endRes = !res;            // 0x80000000 -> 0x00000000, 0x00000000 -> 0x00000001
    printf("mask %x newX %x newY %x add %x ~mask %x res %x endRes %x\n",mask, newX, newY, add, ~mask, res, endRes);
    return endRes;
}
```

The function prints the following for x = 0x80000000 and y = 0x80000000:

```
mask 7fffffff newX 40000000 newY 40000000 add 80000000 ~mask 80000000 res 0 endRes 1
```

Now my question is why is `res` 0? it should be 0x80000000 because both `add` and `~mask` are 0x80000000. Can anyone explain this behavior to me?

Comment: Can not reproduce: http://ideone.com/an8ocK

Comment: You know shifting into the sign bit [is bad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009885/arithmetic-bit-shift-on-a-signed-integer), right? Any particular reason you're not just using `INT_MAX` rather than trying to contrive it on your own?

Comment: Ok thanks; this is strange. I'm not supposed to use any constants larger than one byte for this task.

Comment: Can you try the same code on a different machine e.g. linux?

Comment: Which OS, which compiler version?

Comment: I just used the make command in my terminal. `make -v
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0`. My Mac is on a 64 bit architecture.

Comment: @user3273046 Then why are you targeting i386? That's 32bit.

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but your algorithm is broken.  It will claim that `addOK(0xffffffff, 1)` doesn't have an overflow, when in fact it does.

Comment: Are you shooting for signed or unsigned overflow?  All of your values are signed, but you're apparently only looking for a carry-out of bit 31, which is not a signed overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I tried my code on a Linux 32-bit and there the particular issue stated above did not occur.

I conclude the problem was due to the OS and/or the compiler I was using. Since I didn't write the tests or the makefile myself and am not familiar enough with C so far, I still don't understand exactly what went wrong.

But as pat pointed out (thank you)

> Are you shooting for signed or unsigned overflow? All of your values are signed, but you're apparently only looking for a carry-out of bit 31, which is not a signed overflow. -pat

the algorithm I wrote was broken in the first place. I had the wrong idea of the overflow in my mind. I had to check for the signed overflow which occurs when either two negative ints are added and overflow to a positive one or two positive numbers to a negative one. (According to two's complement arithmetic).

If anyone is interested here is my working code:

```
int addOK(int x, int y) {
    int mask = 1 << 31;   // 0x80000000
    int msbX = mask & x;  // Set all bit to 0 except sign bit
    int msbY = mask & y; 
    int msbSum = mask & (x + y);
    int prob1 = !(msbX ^ msbY);   // == 1 iff x and y have the same sign - thats when an overflow may occur
    int prob2 = !(msbX ^ msbSum); // == 0 iff x + y and x have a different sign - thats when an overfolow may occur
    return (!prob1) | prob2;      // There is an overflow iff prob1 == 1 and prob2 == 0
}
```

In this code the problem I asked about above doesn't even occur and I'm able to run it directly on my mac again.