# Can I use int type to use as netmask of a IP address in C?

Tags: c, ip, bitwise-operators, netmask

I need to "AND" a IP address with its subnet mask.
IP address is a hexadecimal number and the subnet mask is a number between 0 - 32 (not 0).

```
4a21bd6e/25
```

Can I use the bellow code to "AND" these two variables to obtain most significant 25 bits of the IP address?

```
uint32_t IP = 4a21bd6e;
uint8_t netmask = 25;
int mask = 0x80000000;
uint32_t results = IP & (mask  >> (netmask - 1));
```

Comment: did you try it? what did you expect and what was the result?

Comment: I edit two last line code, it works well but I want to be sure.

Comment: an IPv4 address is a 4 byte value and an IPv4 subnet mask is also a 4 byte value.  Please explain what it is you are attempting to do with the shifting.  if you want the most significant 25 bits then just use a hex value for that value.

Comment: We can show subnet mask by a number between 0 to 32. If we want to obtain most significant netmask bits we have to "AND" the IP address with somthing like 0xff000000 (8 bits netmask) but if we have 8 instead of 0xff000000 how can we perform this ?

Comment: @RichardChambers What's a "hex"-value? Please more specific/accurate.

Comment: Reading this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4009922/694576 might help.

Comment: The hex value is : uint32_t IP = 0x4a21bd6e;. I forgot the "0x"..

Answer (score 1):

The answer is *maybe* - if your compiler/processor choice does:

[Arithmetic bit-shift on a signed integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009885/arithmetic-bit-shift-on-a-signed-integer)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use uint32_t like you used for IP? You are assuming int is 4 bytes but that is not always the case. Generally it is better to use standard types as it is more portable and not architecture specific.