# Bit wise operators

Tags: c

am having a little trouble with this function of mine. We are supposed to use bit wise operators only (that means no logical operators and no loops or if statements) and we aren't allowed to use a constant bigger than 0xFF.

I got my function to work, but it uses a huge constant. When I try to implement it with smaller numbers and shifting, I can't get it to work and I'm not sure why.

The function is supposed to check all of the even bits in a given integer, and return 1 if they are all set to 1.

Working code

```
 int allEvenBits(int x) {
 /* implements a check for all even-numbered bits in the word set to 1 */
 /* if yes, the program outputs 1 WORKING */

 int all_even_bits = 0x55555555;
 return (!((x & all_even_bits) ^ all_even_bits)); 
 }
```

Trying to implement with a smaller constant and shifts

```
int allEvenBits(int x) {
/* implements a check for all even-numbered bits in the word set to 1 */
/* if yes, the program outputs 1 WORKING */

int a, b, c, d, e = 0;
int mask = 0x55;

/* first 8 bits */
a = (x & mask)&1;

/* second eight bits */
b = ((x>>8) & mask)&1;

/* third eight bits */
c = ((x>>16) & mask)&1;

/* fourth eight bits */
d = ((x>>24) & mask)&1;
e = a & b & c & d;
return e;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You could also build that mask from small enough constants and then use the code that you know works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do, for example, this:

```
d = ((x>>24) & mask)&1;
```

..you're actually checking whether the lowest bit (with value 1) is set, not whether any of the the mask bits are set... since the `&1` at the end bitwise ANDs the result of the rest with `1`.  If you change the `&1` to `== mask`, you'll instead get `1` when all of the bits set in `mask` are set in `(x>>24)`, as intended.  And of course, the same problem exists for the other similar lines as well.

If you can't use comparisons like `==` or `!=` either, then you'll need to shift all the interesting bits into the same position, then AND them together and with a mask to eliminate the other bit positions.  In two steps, this could be:

```
/* get bits that are set in every byte of x */
x = (x >> 24) & (x >> 16) & (x >> 8) & x;
/* 1 if all of bits 0, 2, 4 and 6 are set */
return (x >> 6) & (x >> 4) & (x >> 2) & x & 1;
```

Comment: `no loops or if statements`

Comment: @Lashane Where do you see a loop or `if` statement in my answer?  I just suggested changing an operator.

Comment: `d = ((x>>24) & mask) && 1;` this is `if`, just short form, and actually wrong according to requirements to test that _all even_ bits are 1

Comment: @Lashane That's *not* `if`... it's logical AND, returning 1 when true and 0 when false.

Comment: `no logical operators`

Comment: also, logical and returns `non-zero` if true, it could be 0xff, or 0x80

Comment: @Lashane Logical AND is actually required to return 1 for true.

Comment: Thanks a ton for all the help. I did not catch that the &1 was only checking that first bit.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you are ANDing your values with 1. What is the purpose of that?

This code is untested, but I would do something along the lines of the following.

```
int allEvenBits(int x) {
    return (x & 0x55 == 0x55) &&
        ((x >> 8) & 0x55 == 0x55) &&
        ((x >> 16) & 0x55 == 0x55) &&
        ((x >> 24) & 0x55 == 0x55);
}
```

Comment: `no loops or if statements`

Comment: Ok, missed that requirement. Updated my answer.

Comment: `no logical operators`

Comment: Rightshifting signed integers is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @abligh: Cite please.

Comment: @JonathanWood see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009885/arithmetic-bit-shift-on-a-signed-integer whilst I go find the bit (not) in the standard

Comment: @JonathanWood and the resultant vulnerabilities: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT13-C.+Use+bitwise+operators+only+on+unsigned+operands

Comment: @abligh: Ok, thanks. That surprises me. I would always expect signed values to shift 1s into the highest order bits when the value is negative, and to shift 0s into the highest order bits when the value is positive. Wasn't aware some implementations might do otherwise.

Comment: @JonathanWood ISO/IEC 9899:TC3 6.5.7/5 "The result of E1 >> E2 is E1 right-shifted E2 bit positions. If E1 has an unsigned type or if E1 has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of E1 / 2E2. If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined."

Comment: @JonathanWood yep it surprised the hell out of me when I found it, and more so when I discovered it causes real bugs rather than being "almost guaranteed" to be an arithmetic shift right.

Comment: @abligh: But I'm not seeing how that would affect the results of the code I posted, since it masks the bits I'm interested in.

Comment: @JonathanWood simply because UB means that (-1 >> 8) could evaluate to 0 - UB is UB - (and thus the answer would be wrong).

Answer (score 1):

Say you are checking the first 4 least significant digits, the even ones would make `1010`. Now you should AND this with the first 4 bits of the number you're checking against. All 1's should remain there. So the test would be `((number & mask) == mask)` (mask is 1010) for the 4 least significant bits, you do this in blocks of 4bits (or you can use 8 since you are allowed).

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't allowed to use constants larger than `0xff` and your existing program works, how about replacing:

```
int all_even_bits = 0x55555555;
```

by:

```
int all_even_bits = 0x55;
all_even_bits |= all_even_bits << 8;  /* it's now 0x5555 */
all_even_bits |= all_even_bits << 16; /* it's now 0x55555555 */
```

Some of the other answers here right shift signed integers (i.e. `int`) which is undefined behaviour.

An alternative route is:

```
int allevenbitsone(unsigned int a)
{
    a &= a>>16; /* superimpose top 16 bits on bottom */ 
    a &= a>>8;  /* superimpose top 8 bits on bottom */
    a &= a>>4;  /* superimpose top 4 bits on bottom */
    a &= a>>2;  /* and down to last 2 bits */
    return a&1; /* return & of even bits */
}
```

What this is doing is and-ing together the even 16 bits into bit 0, and the odd 16 bits into bit 1, then returning bit 0.

Answer (score 0):

the main problem in your code that you're doing &1, so you take first 8 bits from number, mask them with 0x55 and them use only 1st bit, which is wrong

consider straightforward approach:

```
int evenBitsIn8BitNumber(int a) {
    return (a & (a>>2) & (a>>4) & (a>>6)) & 1;
}

int allEvenBits(int a) {
    return evenBitsIn8BitNumber(a) &
        evenBitsIn8BitNumber(a>>8) &
        evenBitsIn8BitNumber(a>>16) &
        evenBitsIn8BitNumber(a>>24);
}
```

Comment: Rightshifting signed integers is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @abligh actually it is _implementation dependent_, in any case - there is no difference for this code whether sign bit will be promoted or not