# Inconsistent left logical shift behavior

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I am developing a simple C app on a CentOS linux machine my university owns and I am getting very strange inconsistent behavior with the `<<` operator.

Basically I am attempting to shift `0xffffffff` left based on a variable `shiftNum` which is based on variable `n`

```
int shiftNum = (32 + (~n + 1));
int shiftedBits = (0xffffffff << shiftNum);
```

This has the effect of shifting `0xffffffff` left `32-n` times and works as expected. However when `n = 0` and `shiftNum = 32` I get some very strange behaviour. Instead of getting the expected `0x00000000` I get `0xffffffff`.

For example this script:

```
int n = 0;
int shiftNum  = (32 + (~n + 1));
int shiftedBits = (0xffffffff << shiftNum );
printf("n: %d\n",n);
printf("shiftNum: 0x%08x\n",shiftNum);
printf("shiftedBits: 0x%08x\n",shiftedBits);
int thirtyTwo = 32;
printf("ThirtyTwo: 0x%08x\n",thirtyTwo);
printf("Test: 0x%08x\n", (0xffffffff << thirtyTwo));
```

Outputs:

```
n: 0
shiftNum: 0x00000020
shiftedBits: 0xffffffff
ThirtyTwo: 0x00000020
Test: 0x00000000
```

I have no idea what is going on honestly. Some crazy low-level something I suspect. Even more strange the operation `(0xffffffff << (shiftNum -1)) << 1` outputs `0x00000000`.

Does anyone have any clue whats going on?

Comment: If you are left shifting a signed quantity you may get undefined behaviour.

Comment: This question has been asked before, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009885/arithmetic-bit-shift-on-a-signed-integer and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622/shift-operator-in-c

Comment: My question is completely about left bit shifting. Those two questions you just linked were about the differences between `<<` and `>>` . I understand that the MSB gets copied when shifting right but that has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: Both questions discuss shifts in both directions. You can't have read past the first sentence.

Comment: See Jonathan Leffler's answer, just an additional note. It is likely that your compiler here takes the simplest path, just producing an assembly shift instruction with the given count operand as-is. On Intel 32 bits, only the low 5 bits of this count operand is used, so your 32 will essentially turn into a 0, that's how you get 0xFFFFFFFF. Here the undefined behavior so played out this way, on some other system, it may play out in some other way.

Answer (score 1):

If you invoke undefined behaviour, the results are unspecified and anything is valid.

When `n` is 0, `32 + (~n + 1)` is 32 (on a two's complement CPU).  If `sizeof(shiftNum) == 4` (or `sizeof(shiftNum) * CHAR_BIT == 32`, which usually has the same result), then you are only allowed to shift by values 0..31; anything else is undefined behaviour.

> #### ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators:
>
> If the value of the right operand is negative or is
> greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.

The result, therefore, is correct — even if you get a different answer each time you run the code, or recompile the program, or anything else.