# How to copy uint8_t array in char array in c

Tags: c, arrays, uint8t

I would copy a uint8_t array in a char array.
I tried different solutions with: cast, memcopy, strcpy...
but it does not work!!! My little example is:

```
uint32_t num = 123456789;
printf("\n num: %"PRIu32 "\n", num);
uint32_t x;
uint8_t a[4];
char b[4];

num=htonl(num);

a[0]=num;
a[1]=num>>8;
a[2]=num>>16;
a[3]=num>>24;

b[0] = a[0];
b[1] = a[1];
b[2] = a[2];
b[3] = a[3];



printf("\nA: %x %x %x %x", a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]);
printf("\nB: %x %x %x %x", b[0],b[1],b[2],b[3]);


x= b[0] | b[1]<<8 | b[2]<<16 | b[3]<<24;

x=ntohl(x);
printf("\n x vale: %"PRIu32 "\n", x);
}
```

The prints are:

```
num: 123456789
A: 7 5b cd 15
B: 7 5b ffffffcd 15
x: 123457023
```

Why I get a differente number in x?

Comment: If [`CHAR_BIT`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits#Limits_of_integer_types) is 8 (meaning `char` is 8 bits), then just do a `memcpy` call?

Comment: Chars are signed. Mind it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. `char` can be signed. Or unsigned. It's up to the implementation.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg In this case they are clearly signed. But yes.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Since when? The signed-ness of `char` is implementation defined.

Comment: Why are you calling `htonl` and `ntohl`?

Comment: Your code invokes undefined behaviour for certain values. General advice is to bit-shift only unsigned integers and use fixed-width types. Strange enough, as you already use them in some places. However, your code-stubs does not match the title of your question. See [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Some implementations may not have `uintN_t` (for N in (8, 32)). If you want portability (for all kinds of implementations in a few centuries from now on) prefer `uintleastN_t`

Comment: `x = b[0] | (b[1] & 0x000000FF)<<8 | (b[2] & 0x000000FF)<<16 | (b[3] & 0x000000FF)<<24;`

Comment: I solved!!!  Thank you @LPs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify your code a little to be sure to handle some undefined behavior, such as `signed int` value overflow.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main()
{
    uint32_t num = 123456789;
    printf("\n num: %" PRIu32 "\n", num);
    uint32_t x;
    uint8_t a[4];
    unsigned char b[4];

    num=htonl(num);

    a[0] = num & 0x000000FFu;
    a[1] = (num & 0x0000FF00u) >> 8;
    a[2] = (num & 0x00FF0000u) >>16;
    a[3] = (num & 0xFF000000u) >>24;

    b[0] = a[0];
    b[1] = a[1];
    b[2] = a[2];
    b[3] = a[3];


    printf("\nA: %x %x %x %x", a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]);
    printf("\nB: %x %x %x %x", b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3]);


    x = b[0] | (b[1] & 0x000000FFu)<<8 | (b[2] & 0x000000FFu)<<16 | (b[3] & 0x000000FFu)<<24;

    x = ntohl(x);

    printf("\n x vale: %" PRIu32 "\n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see:

1. `b` array is declared as `unsigned char` to avoid [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4009922/3436922). It also correct values printed by 3rd `printf` in your code.
2. Inserting value into `a` array it is more clear if you mask bits you want to move before shift them in the correct position.
3. When you calculate `x` value you are performing left shift on `8 bit` variables. So you are loosing all bits after 8 shift. &ing them with a `32 bit HEX literal` you can be sure to use the correct size for bit shift and for `or`s

About point 3, as @2501 pointed out, you must use u for literals to be sure to avoid UB on platform where `int` has a size smaller than 32 bts or where signed int has trap values. See 6.4.4.1. p5 of standard.

Comment: If the width of int is less than 32 bits or if signed integer representation has some trap values, then this code has ub when the left shifts are made due to integer promotions.

Comment: @2501 Well, yes, but I though It is too complicate to wrote that well understandable for OP level. BTW My comment was enough. I cancel my inaccurate answer.

Comment: Well the solution is really simple just use an unsigned version of: `0x000000FFu`

Comment: @2501 Weird, Aren't hex literals always unsigned?

Comment: Not If they fit into an `int`. See 6.4.4.1. p5

Comment: @2501 I got it now. I'm a moron and I really need to go to sleep ;)

Comment: You can also shift then mask, e.g. `a[1] = (num  >> 8) & 0xFF;`, your choice.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, sure. For me it is more clear to mask and shift. So at first look I see which bits are affected by the formula.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why a call to `memcpy` should not work. Simply check for `CHAR_BIT == 8` to be sure `char` is defined as an 8 bit type (some implemetations define `char` to be 16 Bit big) and then call `memcpy(b, a, sizeof(b) / sizeof(b[0]))`. This should to the trick. 
Don't forget to include `string.h` for `memcpy` and `limits.h` for `CHAR_BIT`.

---

As others have pointed out you could still get trouble with this, since the signed-ness of `char` is implementation defined as well. Therefore you should declare `b` as `unsigned char` to prevent undefined behavior.

To be 100% save you should also check that `a` and `b` do have the same size so you won't get any runtime errors.