# convert signed integer array in big endian to hexa decimal 16 bit in little endian in c

Tags: c, endianness

I am new to the endians.
I am trying to convert a big endian integer array to hexadecimal string in little endian. I tried to convert big endian integer array to little endian hexa decimal string. But at the end, getting big endian hexa decimal encoded string instead of little endian. Please help me

```
gint16 frame[5] = {10, -26, 35, 7, -35};  //big endian 
gint16 frame_i[5];
size_t i;
for (i= 0; i < 5; i++) {
  frame_i[i] = (frame[i] << 8) | ((frame[i] >> 8) & 0xFF);  //big endian to little endian
}
char *str = malloc(5 * 4 + 1);
size_t j;
for (j= 0; j < 5; j++) {
    snprintf(str + j * 4, 5, "%04X", frame_i[j] & 0xFFFF); // getting big endian  instead of little endian
}
```

Comment: I cannot imagine why you need a little-endian string. Text representations of numbers are always m.s. digit first. Endianness has nothing to do with how arrays are organised: the issue is the byte sequence in memory that a multi-byte value is naturally stored by the processor. Please [read about endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: Moreover this line `(frame_i[i] << 8) | ((frame_i[i] >> 8) & 0xFF);` has no effect - the expression's value is not assigned.

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that will avoid silly mistakes in the question, leaving doubt there might be more transcription errors.

Comment: sorry. will check in future post

Comment: @WeatherVane "Text representations of numbers are always m.s. digit first." --> How about a text representation like "fourteen" (four + ten)? ;-)

Comment: @chux you got me there, also `four-and-twenty` but you know what I meant. Even Arabic which is written right-to-left, writes numbers left-to-right. But the Romans didn't. Anyway `four + ten` are not digits, they are words.

Comment: @WeatherVane That's a [big 10-4](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/66948/51392) good buddy.

Comment: @chux `10-10` with your `20/20`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `(frame_i[i] << 8) | ((frame_i[i] >> 8) & 0xFF);` has no effect (you would have noticed that, if you had used `-Wall` compiler option). Also, you should apply this operation on the `frame` variable, and store the result in `frame_i`, e.g.:

```
int16_t frame[5] = {10, -26, 35, 7, -35};
int16_t frame_i[5] = {0};
size_t i;

for (i = 0; i < sizeof(frame) / sizeof(int16_t); i++) {
  frame_i[i] = (frame[i] << 8) | ((frame[i] >> 8) & 0xFF);
}

for (i = 0; i < sizeof(frame) / sizeof(int16_t); i++) {
  printf("%04X -> %04X\n", frame[i] & 0xFFFF, frame_i[i] & 0xFFFF);
}
```

*Output*

```
000A -> 0A00
FFE6 -> E6FF
0023 -> 2300
0007 -> 0700
FFDD -> DDFF
```

Note, as *@WeatherVane* has pointed out, the right shift of a negative signed integer has implementation-defined behavior. See answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009885/arithmetic-bit-shift-on-a-signed-integer) question. Consider using an unsigned type, e.g. `uint16_t` from `stdint.h`.

Comment: Please use `unsigned` types for such shifting?

Comment: @WeatherVane, do you mean that the right shift is implementation-defined for signed?

Comment: Yes I did mean that.

Comment: Minor point: `sizeof(frame) / sizeof(int16_t)` is OK, yet consider `sizeof (frame) / sizeof(frame[0])` or  `sizeof (frame) / sizeof(*frame)`  or  `sizeof frame / sizeof *frame`.  Coding only the variable, and not its type, makes for easier maintenance.