# char type bitwise operation fails in to int

Tags: c, type-conversion, bit-manipulation, integer-promotion, type-promotion

I am try to bitwise operate in C. Here is my code:

```
int main() {
    char c = 127;
    c <<= 1;
    if (c == 0xfe) {
        printf("yes");
    }
    else {
        printf("No");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

System console print No.
What I expect to receive is Yes.
the value in c after bit moving is ffffffffe.
It seems that system has changed 8bits to a 32bits. Can anyone help me.

Comment: You should almost always use unsigned types when doing bitwise operations.

Comment: What is mechanism behind bitwise operation. What is the difference. Can you refer me so some paper relating to this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009885/arithmetic-bit-shift-on-a-signed-integer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have correctly figured out the content of the lower byte, i.e. `0xfe`. However, there is more to what's actually happening here: when you write

```
if (c == 0xfe) {
    ...
}
```

you are comparing `c`, a `char`, to an `int` constant `0xfe`. In this situation C rules require *promoting* `char c` to `int` for comparison. Since `char` is signed on your platform, `0xfe` gets promoted to `0xfffffffe`, which is why the comparison subsequently fails.

If you want to do the comparison in `char` type, cast `0xfe` to `char`, like this:

```
if (c == (char)0xfe) {
    ...
}
```

[Demo 1.](https://ideone.com/echGVy)

Unsigned characters, on the other hand, would give you no trouble with `int` promotion, because they fit nicely in an `int`:

```
unsigned char c = 127;
c<<=1;
if (c == 0xfe) { // No casting is necessary
    ...
}
```

[Demo 2.](https://ideone.com/IsMLqY)

**Note:** The behavior of `c <<= 1` is implementation-defined due to `char` overflow.

Comment: Note the behavior in `c <<= 1;` is implementation defined, due to the overflow.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I was really trying to figure out what is value in c after bit moving. When I printf value in c it shows 0xffff fffe.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That's true, an so is the behavior of sign-extending the value. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: `c = 0xfffffffe` after bit moving. it is promoted to 64 bits. Is there a way that doing bit moving would not promote type?

Comment: @Akrios The value of `c` is `0xfe`, the remaining `f`s are added by integer promotion in the call to `printf`. In other words, when you print `printf("%x", c)` you are printing `(int)c`, not simply `c`, because C standard does the conversion as part of the call to a vararg function.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Correct me if I am wrong. Essentially, the value in `c` still is `0xfe` but it is promoted by calling `printf()` function. ·

Comment: @Akrios `0xfffffffe` is only 32 bits (8 nibbles of 4 bit each). It's not the move that promotes to `int`, it's other operations that do it: printing, comparisons, etc. C does this a lot, so you need to be careful when you work with signed characters. Unsigned characters, on the other hand, would give you no trouble at all Please see the edit.

Comment: @Akrios Yes, that's exactly right. `c` is `0xfe`, but the call to `printf` promotes it to `int`, performing sign extension as part of the process.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That is so great. unsigned solves problem.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I guess not only `printf()` promotes my c but also doing `==` also promote c to `int` right?

Comment: @Akrios Yes, that's right, any comparison operation with `int` would promote `char` to `int`. Same goes with arithmetic operators - if you try `int x = ...; int y = c + x` the value of `c` would be promoted to `int` for the addition.