# Printf() printing character as 32 bit

Tags: c, printf

I'm running a quick test to make sure I have my pointer arithmetic down:

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ADDRESS    0xC0DCA11501LL
#define LENGTH     5


void print_address( char *, char );

/* Main program */
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    char nums[ LENGTH ];

    /* LSB first */
    for( int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++ )
    {
        nums[ i ] = ( ADDRESS >> ( 8 * i ) ) & 0xFF;
    }

    print_address( nums, LENGTH );

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}

void print_address( char *data, char len )
{
     char *data_ptr = data;

     while( len-- )
     {
            printf( "%X\n", *data_ptr++ );
     }
}
```

What I expect is the bytes of `ADDRESS` to be printed out LSB first in hex format.  But the last 3 bytes appear to be printed with 32-bit lengths:

```
1
15
FFFFFFA1
FFFFFFDC
FFFFFFC0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Is this due to my bit-shifting arithmetic, something compiler-specific, some `printf()` behavior?

(I'm using MinGW GCC v6.3.0 on Windows 10 to compile.)

Comment: Betcha that char is a signed value and that you are seeing the FFFFs because A1 is greater than 0x80 and is showing up signed.  Try using unsigned char pointer.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan D'oh!  You're right -- changing the A, D, and C to 7s made it go away.

Comment: I'll make it a quick answer then.

Comment: also `0xC0DCA11501LL` should be `0xC0DCA11501ULL`. Shifting signed integers is undefined behaviour

Comment: Shifting negative signed integers in undefined.  Shift positive signed integers is implementation defined.  Still, unsigned is a better choice in these cases for many reasons.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009885/arithmetic-bit-shift-on-a-signed-integer

Comment: Also use unsigned char for the `nums` array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that your `char` is a being used as a signed value and that you are seeing the `FFFF`s because `0xA1` is greater than `0x80` and is therefore showing up signed. Try using unsigned char pointer (and for the `nums` array and `data` in your function prototype) and the problem should go away.

Comment: I assume that "_Betcha_" is a slang for "_I bet that_". Is my assumption correct?

Comment: Yes - sorry for the slang.  Betcha is I bet that.

Comment: Please compile it and let me know how that works. Because that was also my first guess but it didn't work to me. If it works, I remove my answer. If it does not work, upvote mine :-)

Answer (score 2):

Type `char` seems to be signed in your environment, such that `A1` as an 8 bit value actually represents a negative number. Note then that the `varargs` of `printf` are promoted to int type, and a negative number is filled up with leading `1`-bits. In other words, signed `A1` when promoted to 32 bit integer will give `FFFFFFA1`. That's why.

Use `unsigned char` instead:

```
void print_address( unsigned char *, char );

/* Main program */
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    unsigned char nums[ LENGTH ];

    /* LSB first */
    for( int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++ )
    {
        nums[ i ] = ( ADDRESS >> ( 8 * i ) ) & 0xFF;
    }

    print_address( nums, LENGTH );

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}

void print_address( unsigned char *data, char len )
{
    unsigned char *data_ptr = data;

    while( len-- )
    {
        printf( "%X\n", *data_ptr++ );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that printf does not know that the type of your data is char.

Try this

```
void print_address( char *data, char len )
{
     char *data_ptr = data;

     while( len-- )
     {
            printf( "%02X\n", *data_ptr++ &0xFF);
     }
}
```

Result:

```
[jmgomez@d1 tmp]$ a.o
01
15
A1
DC
C0
sh: PAUSE: command not found
[jmgomez@d1 tmp]$
```

Comment: While this does work, it does so by hiding the signed/unsigned issue with truncation.  Better to work with unsigned when doing byte work to prevent the issue beforehand.