# How does shift operators affect unsigned numbers

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

Suppose `x` is unsigned int

Then is `x << n` equal to **x * 2<sup>n</sup>**

I know it's true for signed integers.

Is `x * 15` **equal** to `x << 4 - x`?

Comment: C/c++ programming

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arithmetic bit-shift on a signed integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009885/arithmetic-bit-shift-on-a-signed-integer)

Comment: @Shabaz There's no such language as C/C++. There's C and C++. They're separate languages.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for the C language. There seems to be subtle differences in the C++ specification for this particular question.

If `x` is unsigned **and** if `n >= 0` and less than the number of value bits in the type of `x`, `x << n` is indeed the same as multiplying `x` by the n-th power of 2.

If this computation overflows, the result will reduced modulo the largest value for the type of `x` plus 1.

If `x` is signed, it must be non-negative the result must not overflow or you will get undefined behavior. A common case of undefined behavior on 32-bit architectures is this:

```
unsigned x = 1 << 31;   /* undefined behavior: 1 is signed, 31 is too large */
```

The correct version is:

```
unsigned x = 1U << 31;   /* correct on 32 bit architectures */
```

Incidentally, Since C++14, the C++ Standard has a specific provision for this very case:

*the value of `a << b` is a times 2<sup>b</sup> if it is representable in the unsigned version of the return type (which is then converted to signed: this makes it legal to create `INT_MIN` as `1 << 31`), otherwise the behavior is undefined.*

Regarding your second question, is `x * 15` equal to `x << 4 - x`?

The answer is no because `x << 4 - x` is parsed as `x << (4 - x)`.

If you parenthesize your expression, then indeed `x * 15 == (x << 4) - x`.

Note however that it is not correct for signed values, because the intermediary result `x << 4` could overflow for large values of `x` for which the result of `x * 15` would not.

Comment: In C++, there is a strange special provision to avoid making 1<<31 UB.

Comment: They made it implementation-defined because Howard Hinnant was sick of having to mangle his code to avoid the UB

Comment: @MarcGlisse: Did C++ ditch the non 2's complement architectures and padding-bits and trap-values alike? How much sense does it make to keep these anyway?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_shift_operators (see the "since C++14" part). Or check the standard directly.