# Bit rotation with signed char (C)?

Tags: c, types, binary, rotation, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to rotate a signed char (`*c`), which in binary is `10011010`, right 4 (`numRotate`) places. The desired outcome after the shift is `10101001`. The code I currently have is:

```
void right(char *c, int numRotate) {
    *c = (*c >> numRotate) | (*c << (8 - numRotate));
}
```

According to what I've learnt, this apparently should work to do my desired shift correctly. Instead the outcome I have been getting is `11111001`. I'm not sure what's wrong. Could it be a problem with `signed` vs `unsigned` `char` data types? All the resources I've looked at only use unsigned data types.

Comment: the fact of data type being signed or unsigned has no relation to the bit order. well, unless you do arithmetic operations on it, like subtraction above. bitwise operations like shifts do not take a sign into account

Comment: Convert the `*c` to `unsigned char` before shifting.  Your compiler does an arithmetic shift right on signed types, and plain `char` appears to be a signed type on your machine.  (`*c = ((unsigned char)(*c) >> numRotate) | ((unsigned char)(*c) << (8 - numRotate));`)

Comment: @mangusta It's indeed related to the fact that `*c` is signed. Shift right on signed variable is implementation defined. Cast it to `unsigned char` before the shifts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arithmetic bit-shift on a signed integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009885/arithmetic-bit-shift-on-a-signed-integer)

Comment: @AlexLop do you mean implementation of C standard library? i thought if we shift say 11111111 (a byte-sized data type) to left once, we get 11111110, no matter what the sign is. The OP complains about bit pattern she gets, not its numeric value

Comment: @mangusta I was talking about shift right, not left.

Comment: @Moca: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 0):

It has been answered in other post [Arithmetic bit-shift on a signed integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009885/arithmetic-bit-shift-on-a-signed-integer). To get the result you expect you should use unsigned char.

```
void right(unsigned char *c, int numRotate) {
    *c = (*c >> numRotate) | (*c << (8 - numRotate));
}
```

With signed integer right shift operator will pad the remaining space with the sign bit (MSB) so:

```
10011010 >> 4 == 11111001
01011010 >> 4 == 00000101
```

The answer from the question I linked states it is compiler/platform specific. It is so to make common optimization technique of replacing multiplication/division by powers of 2 with bitshift operations work with negative numbers. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char x = -4;
    printf("0x%x -> %i\n", x, x);

    x <<= 1; //multiply by 2^1 = 2
    printf("0x%x -> %i\n", x, x);

    x >>= 2; //divide by 2^2 =4
    printf("0x%x -> %i\n", x, x);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0xfffffffc -> -4
0xfffffff8 -> -8
0xfffffffe -> -2
```

Answer (score 0):

Right shifting a negative value has implementation defined behavior. The pattern `10011010` has a negative value if `char` is 8-bit wide and signed by default on your platform. You must use `unsigned char` to have defined behavior for your purpose:

```
void right(char *c, int numRotate) {
    *c = ((unsigned char)*c >> numRotate) | ((unsigned char)*c << (8 - numRotate));
}
```