# Why bit-shift in two steps?

Tags: c, linux, bit-manipulation, unspecified-behavior

In the [Linux kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/5bfc75d92efd494db37f5c4c173d3639d4772966/fs/read_write.c#L994), I found the following code:

```
static inline loff_t pos_from_hilo(unsigned long high, unsigned long low)
{
#define HALF_LONG_BITS (BITS_PER_LONG / 2)
    return (((loff_t)high << HALF_LONG_BITS) << HALF_LONG_BITS) | low;
}
```

The code is used to combine syscall arguments into one wider variable, so for example on ia32 the offset of `pwritev` is specified in two 32 bit registers.

On x64, `loff_t` and `unsigned long` are both 64 bit wide. In this case, the `high` variable is ignored and only `low` is used. On ia32, `loff_t` is 64 bit wide and `unsigned long` is 32 bit wide. In this case the two arguments `high` and `low` are combined.

I was wondering why the code bit-shifts twice instead of once. There's a bit more information about this code in the [commit message](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/601cc11d054ae4b5e9b5babec3d8e4667a2cb9b5) and in an LWN article: [System calls and 64-bit architectures](https://lwn.net/Articles/311630/), but no explanation for the double bit-shift.

Answer (score 4):

The following warning in a test app helped my figure this out:

```
test.c:8:27: warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
    8 |     return (((loff_t)high << (2*HALF_LONG_BITS))) | low;
```

The double bit-shift protects against undefined behavior. From the [C spec](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf):

> 6.5.7 3) ... If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.

On a 64 bit machine both `loff_t` and `long` are 64 bits wide. If we did the shift at once, we would shift `high` by 64 bits which according to the statement above is undefined behavior. Doing it in two steps makes `high` into 0.

---

PS: I wrote a test program to investigate this and to my surprise I got different results when I replaced the two bit-shifts with a single bit-shift.

Comment: I'm probably missing something here, but if the (expected?) net result is a left shift by a number of bits exactly equal to the width of the type, why not just `return low;`?

Comment: @Bob__: I think `BITS_PER_LONG` is the width of `unsigned long`, but `loff_t` may be wider. I believe the idea is to have code which will pack `high` and `low` into the return value in case `loff_t` is wider than `unsigned long`, and will simply return `low` if they are the same width.

Comment: @NateEldredge Still, if I'm not mistaken, given the `typedef`s in [/include/linux/types.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/types.h#L46) and [/include/uapi/asm-generic/posix_types.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/posix_types.h#L88), `loff_t` ends up beeing a `long long`, so isn't it [UB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009885/arithmetic-bit-shift-on-a-signed-integer) to fill it with two `unsigned long`?

Comment: @Bob__: The kernel is built with `-fno-strict-overflow`, so signed integer overflow is not UB but instead is guaranteed to wrap around.  So I think everything is fine.  On a system where `unsigned long` is 32 bits and `loff_t` is 64, you pack `high` and `low` into the return value, and if `high` is too big, all that happens is the return value is negative (which is maybe checked elsewhere).  If `unsigned long` and `loff_t` are both 64 bits, then `(((loff_t)high << HALF_LONG_BITS) << HALF_LONG_BITS)` is guaranteed to evaluate to 0, and we just return `low`.

Comment: @NateEldredge I see, thanks. I'd have written something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/zjYoajTjo), but that's immaterial.