How use BigInt that right shift operation and XOR in javascript?
I want move some of bit toward right in javascript, but I found result was not right because I wrote a test program by C language to contradistinction.
I spend whole day who had't  found correct way. please, Could you tell me that right way.
const poly = BigInt('0x42F0E1EBA9EA3693');

let crc = BigInt(1);

for (let k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
  crc = poly ^ (crc >> 1n);
  const c1 = crc & 0xFFFFFFFFn;

  console.log('crc:', c1.toString(16).padStart(8, '0'));
}

// output:
// crc: a9ea3693
// crc: 7d1f2dda
// crc: 9765a07e
// crc: e258e6ac
// crc: 58c645c5
// crc: 05891471
// crc: ab2ebcab
// crc: 7c7d68c6

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
  uint64_t poly = 0x42F0E1EBA9EA3693;

  unsigned int crc = 1;
  for (unsigned int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
  {
    crc = poly ^ (crc >> 1);
    printf("crc: %x\n", crc);
  }

  return 0;
}

// output
// crc: a9ea3693
// crc: fd1f2dda
// crc: d765a07e
// crc: c258e6ac
// crc: c8c645c5
// crc: cd891471
// crc: cf2ebcab
// crc: ce7d68c6

I try used Uint8Array to do it instead of BigInt, but result still error. How can i do ?  How do it ? result can like c language.

Your JS crc is a BigInt of unlimited width. Your C crc is an unsigned int of 32 bits. You want 64 bits there to get the same result. In your C code, the high half of the poly is never used.

there are answers explaining this like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009885/arithmetic-bit-shift-on-a-signed-integer .. the point being that >> behaves as an arithmetic right shift preserving the sign of the first operand. behaving differently on how >>> would by ignoring the sign.

...Since the latter doesn't operate on BigInt you may just double the &&  over 0xFFFFFFFFn so that the second time, the sign information is stripped off. Of course my suggestion revolves around the unsigned int you decided on your C code .. as that is 32 bit unsigned

Tip: Your C program should use uint32_t instead of unsigned int, since unsigned int might not be 32 bits in size.

Your JS loop fails to update crc in the same way as the C program. To achieve the same result as the C program, replace
const c1 = ...

with
crc = ...

This causes the bits of higher-precision to be dropped, just like in the C program.


const poly = BigInt('0x42F0E1EBA9EA3693');

let crc = BigInt(1);

for (let k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
  crc = poly ^ (crc >> 1n);
  crc = crc & 0xFFFFFFFFn;

  console.log('crc:', crc.toString(16).padStart(8, '0'));
}




This does make it match C version... which goes back to my first comment (now deleted) - is OP sure the C version works correctly?

I don't know if they're sure. I'm definitely not since I haven't evaluated the correctness of the C program. I just provided the requested fix. Perhaps the OP shouldn't have asked to translate, but asked how to achieve something. (Translation questions are awful, IMHO, and actually two unrelated questions: "What does program X do?", and "How do I do Y?") But they provided no information about that something other than the C program. Updated the wording of my answer to replace "correct result" with "same result as the C program"

Thank you fro you answer, It turns out that the sign bit is causing trouble.It was careless of me.
Have you good day. Thanks again~

No, having too many bits was causing a problem

Your JS crc is a BigInt of unlimited width. Your C crc is an unsigned int of 32 bits. This means the higher 32 bit of your poly are never used in the crc = poly ^ (crc >> 1); calculation. You want 64 bits there to get the same result:
uint64_t crc = 1;


They asked to duplicate the C behaviour in JS, so you suggested a change to the wrong program.

@ikegami I understood the question to ask why there is a difference between the two programs, with no indication that the C version should be the authoritative one. And even if it is, imo it has a bug, because one wouldn't use a 64 bit polynomial for computing a 32 bit CRC.

Re "with no indication that the C version should be the authoritative one", They said it multiple times. They said the C program is being used to validate the JS program. They said the JS program is giving an error. They said the want a result like the one of the c language program. /// Re "imo it has a bug", It's possible. I haven't evaluated the correctness of the C program.

@ikegami You are right. but the question that I just want to verificate bit of shift operation in javascript. the code of  C language quoted from github. but because of the code too long and my terrible English. I have to modify the code in the question that make the description simple and easy to understand。

@Viweei That code does in fact declare uint64_t crc;. Please edit your question to reflect this, then I'll delete this answer
