# storing negative numbers

Tags: c

In this code below

```
int main()
{
int  a = -1;
printf("%d",a>>1);
return 0;
}
```

Why it is giving output -1.

Comment: See this question [shift operator in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622/shift-operator-in-c).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

bit-shifting is defined only on unsigned types, for signed types it is implementation-defined.
And this is a useful refinement by R..

> Strictly speaking, it is defined for
>   signed types whenever the value is
>   positive and the result does not
>   overflow, and right shift is
>   implementation-defined for negative
>   values. Left shift, on the other hand,
>   is undefined for negative values

```
┌───┬──────────────┬──────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────────┐
│   │ Unsigned     │ Signed, positive                 │ Signed, negative       │
├───┼──────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│<< │ well-defined │ well-defined, except on overflow │ undefined behaviour    │
│>> │ well-defined │ well-defined                     │ implementation-defined │
└───┴──────────────┴──────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, it is defined for signed types whenever the value is positive and the result does not overflow, and right shift is implementation-defined for negative values. Left shift, on the other hand, is *undefined* for negative values.

Comment: I believe that would be "implementation-defined" in C99 according to [Wikipedia: Arithmetic shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift)

Answer (score 5):

Because -1 is 1111111...111 in binary.  `a>>1` operation will "sign extend" the sign bit, so  you get 1111111...111 again.

Comment: This is only in complementary code, which isn't necessarily the way numbers are represented. But still, on many platforms you are right

Comment: @Arment - Agreed, it is definitely machine dependent. I should have pointed that out. Clearly, though, sign extend is what is happening in this particular case.

Comment: @Armen - Don't know if you got previous comment. (Sorry, typo on your name.)

Answer (score 1):

Most compilers choose to interpret `>>` on signed numbers to be arithmetic shift. Thus since the number is initially negative (i.e. the MSB bit is 1), after a right shift, that bit is replaced by another 1 to preserve the sign, ergo you end up with -1 as you started.

Answer (score 0):

The `>>` operator on a signed value may perform an arithmetic or logical shift, depending on the compiler.  Arithmetic shifts retain the sign bit, so `-1` (which on a 2-s complement machine, which these days is pretty much the only variety you will encounter) will remain `-1` when right-shifted.  (Note that the C standard explicitly does not specify whether `>>` on a signed number is an arithmetic or logical shift.  It is always a logical shift on unsigned numbers, though.)

Answer (score 0):

The definition of bit-shifting on signed values is implementation-dependent. Check your compiler's docs for how it handles it.

Answer (score 0):

In Memory signed integer number stored as 2's complement if sign int and when data is read from memory {%d} it's converted into original form so here 2's complement of -1 will stored in memory  let say integer take 2 byte so `2's complement of -1 is 1111 1111 1111 1111`

After perform `a>>1` It will change `0111 1111 1111 1111` now As we know that when data is read from memory it's again converted to 0 complement so take 2's complement of `0111 1111 1111 1111` It will be like `1000 0000 0000 0001` which is equal to -1

**Note:**  2's complement of `+ve` number is same as original binary representation 2's complement is only for `-ve` number. In **C** number always stored as 2's complement form

Comment: First, unsigned numbers are not stored as 2's complement. For signed numbers, not all architectures/compiler implementations use 2's complement too. C standard allows for any other number encoding although it's almost impossible to find a 1's complement or sign-magnitude implementation nowadays

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc : why it's output coming -1 if unsigned is not stored as 2's complement #include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
  unsigned int a = -1;
  printf("%d", a);
}

Comment: unsigned numbers are printed by `%u`, you're getting an undefined behavior

Comment: try printing -1 on computers that use 1's complement or sign-magnitude and see