# C - Bit Shifting is not working as expected

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I am trying to set the least significant bit to all bit places. For instance, `copyLSB(6)` would yield `0x00000000` whereas `copyLSB(5)` would yield `0xffffffff`.

Here is my code:

```
int copyLSB(int x) {
  int r = x << 31;
  r = x >> 31;
  return r;
}
```

The program works for 6 and 5. However, when I input `0x80000000` it fails and returns `0xffffffff`.

Hi guys, I found a way to do this without using bit shifting and this works on signed numbers too.

```
int copyLSB(int x) {                                                                                                   │
        int result = x & 1;                                                                                            │
        return ~(~(x & 0) + result);                                                                                   │
}
```

Comment: Please don't do bit arithmetic on signed values. Please.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thats part of my assignment haha.

Comment: Then your assignment is teaching you practices that would get you fired from my team.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit When do we actually use bitwise operators then?

Comment: @Renren29: With unsigned values.

Comment: go with an unsigned long rather than an int.  results of shifting depends on how the underlying hardware registers do shifting.  with signed values the likelihood of sign extension is very high so that if the high order bit is set and you do a right shift, the hardware will tend to keep the high order bit set.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009885/arithmetic-bit-shift-on-a-signed-integer

Comment: Also see this stack overflow which discusses some of the hardware differences depending on the CPU and instruction set. [why right shifting negative numbers in c brings 1 on the left most bits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358445/why-right-shifting-negative-numbers-in-c-brings-1-on-the-left-most-bits)

Comment: Assuming your system has 32-bit `int`s, an `int` *cannot* hold the value `0x80000000` or `0xffffffff`. The maximum value a 32-bit `int` can hold is `0x7fffffff`, or 2147483647 (2**31-1). You haven't shown us how you're displaying the values; presumably you're doing something that assumes values of type `unsigned int` rather than `int`.

Comment: `0x80000000` is `-2147483648`, `0xffffffff` is `-1`. BTW, you could implement copyLSB without shifts, but the question is why shifts not work.

Comment: @alexander: No, `0x80000000` is not `-2147483648`, it's `+2147483648`. They might happen to have the same representation *in different types*, but they're distinct values. C operators are defined in terms of values, not representations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0x80000000` is a negative number, if your `int`s are 32-bit and [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) is used.

Left shift of negatives is undefined behavior. Right shift of negatives is implementation defined behavior.

From the standard:

> **6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators**
>
> The result of **E1 << E2** is **E1** left-shifted **E2** bit positions; vacated bits are filled with
>   zeros. .... If **E1** has a signed type and nonnegative value, and **E1 × 2^E2** is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.
>
> ....
>
> The result of **E1 >> E2** is **E1** right-shifted **E2** bit positions. ... If **E1** has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined.