# Why the expression -3 >> 1 results in -2?

Tags: java

I'm running this `(-3 >> 1)` in java and getting answer `-2` but according to me, it should be `-1` as I'm thinking this like `-3/2`. Please help me understand this.

```java
int x = -3 >> 1;
System.out.println(x + " " + (-3 >> 1));
```

Comment: @ItFreak That is wrong. Because `int` is signed and -3 is negative, you get a 1-bit when shifting to the right.

Comment: oh yes youre right

Comment: Note also that **-1 >> 1 == -1** (Think of risking endless loops). `-n >> 1 == - (n/2) - (n%2)`

Answer (score 5):

The answer results from the binary representation of -3 in Java, which is

```
11111111111111111111111111111101
```

When you shift these bits right by one you get

```
11111111111111111111111111111110
```

Which is -2.

Comment: For further info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Answer (score 0):

As negetive numbers are saved as 2's complement value for arithmetic operations

Represent -3 in 2's complement

+3 -> 0011

complement ->1100

add 1 -> 0001

-3 -> 1101

after Right shift Operation the value will be 1110 as Right shift operation for negetive number add 1 to left-most bit.

link [Why does right shifting negative numbers in C bring 1 on the left-most bits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358445/why-does-right-shifting-negative-numbers-in-c-bring-1-on-the-left-most-bits)

Represent -2 in 2's complement

+2 -> 0010

complement ->  1101

add 1 ->0001

-2 = -> 1110