# Left shift goes heavily wrong with GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, bit-shift

I've been looking at this piece of code for an hour now... I desperately try to find the error.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for (int32_t n = 1; n>= 0; n--)
    {
        std::cout << "n: " << n << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::dec << "  64 - n: " << (64 - n) << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::hex << "  0x1ULL << 64: " << (0x1ULL << 64) << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::hex << "  0x1ULL << (64 - n): " << (0x1ULL << (64 - n)) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And that's the output:

```
n: 1
  64 - n: 63
  0x1ULL << 64: 0
  0x1ULL << (64 - n): 8000000000000000
n: 0
  64 - n: 64
  0x1ULL << 64: 0
  0x1ULL << (64 - n): 1
```

Why is (0x1ULL << 64) different from (0x1ULL << (64 - n)) for n = 0? The type of n does not seem to matter.

It's the same with each version of GCC. Feel free to try out online:
http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php

Comment: "heavily wrong" I like that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have undefined behaviour:

> C++11 5.8/1 The behavior is undefined if the right operand
>   is negative, or greater than or **equal to the length in bits** of the promoted left operand.

So, assuming `long long` has 64 bits, shifting by 64 bits will give undefined behavoiur.

Comment: +1 Related, in-depth explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22734721/183120).

Comment: Wow, what a daft rule. Whoever created that rule has no clue about processors. The underlying assembler instructions handle those cases correctly. In result, GCCs adds effort to produce undefined behaviour - that's quite an achievement. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: @user3497687: Actually, that rule is because whoever created it *does* know that different processors behave in different ways when a shift overflows; so specifying the behaviour would add effort on processors that naturally behave differently. GCC doesn't "add effort" - it just uses the native shift operation, and gives whatever result that produces.

Answer (score 0):

left shift count should be less that width of type. In this case, width of type int32_t is 32 bits and you are shifting more than its capacity. That's wrong.

Comment: he's not shifting `n`, so the type is not `int32_t`. He's shifting `1ull` (unsigned long long literal)

Comment: Yes, true, even then left shift count should be less that width of type, ull will have 64 bit in width