# What is the logic behind this C program

Tags: c

I came across this C code, compiled and executed it online on an online GCC compiler and received -5 as output. I changed the values of the constants and received different results but couldn't figure out the logic behind the outputs. Please help...

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int a = -10;
   a = a>>1;
   printf("%d", a);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please do not tag your questions with unrelated languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`>>` means "right shift" of the bits of an integer value.  It is equivalent to "/ 2" (divide by 2).

The binary representation of `10` is `1010`.  The binary representation of `-10` is it's 2-complement: `11110110` (assuming 8 bits).  Right shifting 1 bit becomes `11111011`, which is the 2-complement of `101`, or 5 in decimal.  So, `(-10 >> 1) == -5`.

Comment: Thanks a lot... Your answer was simple and to the point... The fact that u preferred using 8 bits to represent the 2-complements,etc. rather than 4 bytes making it look more sophisticated is what I appreciate the most...

Answer (score 3):

In binary notation with two's complement, `a` looks like this:

```
111..1110110
```

Now, a right shift is done. For signed integers it is implementation specific what value the filled bits have; GCC promises "sane behavior", that is, to do an [arithmetic right shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) - where the sign bit (here `1`) is extended.

An arithmetic right shift on an integer is dividing that integer by 2^n (n is the shift size) - no matter the sign.

Therefore the shift produces the new value:

```
111..1111011
```

Which is `-5`. Flipping all bits and adding one yields `000...00101`, which is `5`.

A logical shift would have produced

```
011..1111011
```

which has the value `2147483643` for a 32-bit integer. Note how the value even depends on the size of the integer you performed the operation on.

Comment: Finally someone mentions the sign.

Comment: but the 2's complements are wrong

Comment: @mch Is it correct now?

Comment: -5 is 11111...111011

Comment: @mch Yeah, just saw that too. Never had much to do with shifts and the two's complement :)

Answer (score 1):

`>>` is right shift operator.

`>>1` is shifting right by 1 bit. You can find a detailed discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7622/2173917). For the results, the right-shift is equivalent to a division by 2.

Comment: You'll have to explain why shifting -10 by bit gives -5 :-)

Answer (score 1):

The >> Is the right shift operator. It shifts the bits to the right .

And in this occasion ,it shifts by 1 bit.

Check [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C) and [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/bitshift.html) to study more.

Also , you can find
 [here](http://www.miniwebtool.com/bitwise-calculator/bit-shift/?data_type=10&number=-10&place=1&operator=Shift%20Right) a calculator.

Finally , as "Alter Mann" mentioned , a bitwise right-shift will be the equivalent of integer division by 2.

Comment: Good to say that a bitwise right-shift will be the equivalent of integer division by 2.

Answer (score 1):

According to the C Standard (6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators)

> 5 The result of E1 >> E2 is E1 right-shifted E2 bit positions. If E1
>   has an unsigned type or if E1 has a signed type and a nonnegative
>   value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of
>   E1 / 2E2. **If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the
>   resulting value is implementation-defined**.

it seems that your implementation promotes the sign bit..

So -10 can be represented as (for simplicity I assume that sizeof( int ) is equal to 4)

```
-10
11111111 11111111 11111111 11110110

10 >> 1

11111111 11111111 11111111 11111011
```

The last value is equal to -5.
To be sure that it is equal to 5 you can get its two-complement value that is calculated as

```
~a + 1
a
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111011

~a

00000000 00000000 00000000 00000100

~a + 1

00000000 00000000 00000000 00000101
```

0101 is a binary representation of 5.

Answer (score 0):

The '>>' operator is a bitwise right shift operator (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts), which effectively does a 'divide-by-2'.

The

```
a = a >> 1;
```

statement shifts the number one bit to the right.

Answer (score 0):

this is a bit operation a = 01010 when you make a>>1 you say to your program shift one bit to right and yoour result is 00101.

Answer (score 0):

-10 = 11110110

If you do a>>1
then a = -5

-5 = 11111011

If you do a>>2
then a = -3

-3 = 11111101

Hence, >> is shifting the binary number to one bit right with adding 1 at the starting