# What is the number 0ui64?

Tags: c++, qt

I see the

```
 #define NUM_MAX_VOLUME 0ui64
```

in other people's code

What is the number 0ui64?  It seems it is not a hex number though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am surpsised that there are many answers, but none has pointed out the official and authoritative documentation that should be noted in my opinion, so here goes the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00a1awxf.aspx):

> unsigned-suffix: one of
>
> u U

and

> 64-bit integer-suffix:
>
> i64 LL ll

So, it is indeed not a hexa number, but basically a macro define to zero that represents an unsiged 64 bit integer number. Please note that `0Ui64`, `0ULL`, `0ull`, etc, would be all the same, too.

This is necessary when you want to make sure that the sign and size are fixed so that it cannot go unexpected or undefined behavior.

This is neither standard C++, nor C, but a Microsoft compiler feature. Try to avoid it.

Since your question is tagged as Qt, the recommendation is to use [quint64](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtglobal.html#quint64-typedef) and [Q_UINT64_C](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtglobal.html#Q_UINT64_C) instead which will work cross-platform. So, you would write something like this:

```
#define NUM_MAX_VOLUME Q_UINT64_C(0)
```

Answer (score 4):

"ui64" means unsigned 64-bit integer. It is a non-standard suffix in some cases.
"0ui64" is just 0, and i guess the reason to write like this is for compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

It's basically used in a expression where the size of the operand (the constant here) matters. Take shifting for example:

```
auto i = 1 << 36;
```

On a machine where `int` is 32-bits long this [will lead to undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22734721/183120). Since the `1` here is taken as an `int`, and you're trying to shift it beyond the size of the resulting type: `int`. What you want is a 64-bit integral type, say `unsigned long long` then you'd do

```
auto i = 1ULL << 36;
```

This isn't UB since the resulting type would also be an `unsigned long long` due to the operand (which is now an `unsigned long long` too).

Another example is type deduction of the C++11's `auto` keyword. Try this:

```
for (auto i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
```

With warnings enabled GCC barks ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b7160dca03e18e7))

> warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]

However, changing this to

```
for (auto i = 0u; i < v.size(); ++i)
```

make the warning disappear. Again since the suffix `0u` led the compiler to deduce the type of `i` as `unsigned int` and not simply `int`.

In your case, you've the suffix `ui64` which [isn't standard C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal), so it should be an implementation-specific extension that denotes *unsigned 64-bit integer*.

Comment: `0ULL` makes sense to me, what's the point of bitshifting with `1ULL` though? Why wouldn't you in that context use math.h's `pow(2,36)`

Comment: You can use certainly use the `double` variant of `pow`. However, when the base is 2, instead of using the probably less performant `pow`, people use this bit shifting technique. Also this in a situation where you need the power for an `int`. It is a trick based on the fact that powers of two, in binary, have only one 1 digit.

Comment: I'm confused, what's less performant? They compile to the same assembly: `unsigned long long = pow(2,16);`

Comment: Maybe it's just a style issue and some people find the bit shifting more clear? All good if so?

Comment: Well, your compiler's optimizer is doing a good job then; not all compilers may be this smart. However you need to cast the result back to an `int` additionally, no? The other approach avoids these.

Comment: @EvanCarroll this is definitely not a style thing; it's an optimization back in the days when compilers weren't this smart.

Comment: fair enough `unsigned long long foo = pow(2,4);` just works, generates `mov qword [local_8h], 0x10`. No warning either with `-Wall` using GCC 7.2

Answer (score 0):

`0xFull` ,for example, is also valid C++ constant. It is 0xF, unsigned long long, a.k.a. **ui64** in Microsoft compilers transcription.

Comment: Clever, and raised a smile, but it doesn't really answer the question. Probably would have been better as a comment.

Comment: So basically, it is a very very large number? because 0xF is large.
Or, it is system dependent?

Comment: 0xF = 15 which would normally be an int.  The suffix forces the compiler to consider it to be an unsigned long long but the value of it is still 15.