# Little-endian convention, and saving to a binary file

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, endianness

I have a matrix (2-D int pointer `int **mat`) that I am trying to write to a file in Linux in Little-endian convention.

Here is my function that writes to the file:

```
#define BUFF_SIZE 4
void write_matrix(int **mat, int n, char *dest_file) {
    int i, j;
    char buff[BUFF_SIZE];
    int fd = open(dest_file, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IXUSR);

    if (fd < 0) {
        printf("Error: Could not open the file \"%s\".\n", dest_file);
    }

    buff[0] = (n & 0x000000ff);
    buff[1] = (n & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
    buff[2] = (n & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
    buff[3] = (n & 0xff000000) >> 24;

    write(fd, buff, BUFF_SIZE);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            buff[0] = (mat[i][j] & 0x000000ff);
            buff[1] = (mat[i][j] & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
            buff[2] = (mat[i][j] & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
            buff[3] = (mat[i][j] & 0xff000000) >> 24;

            if (write(fd, buff, BUFF_SIZE) != BUFF_SIZE) {
                close(fd);
                printf("Error: could not write to file.\n");
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    close(fd);
}
```

The problem is that when I write out a matrix large enough of the form `mat[i][i] = i` (let's say 512 X 512), I think I get an overflow, since I get weird negative numbers.

To convert back I use:

```
void read_matrix(int fd, int **mat, int n, char buff[]) {
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            assert(read(fd, buff, BUFF_SIZE) == BUFF_SIZE);
            mat[i][j] = byteToInt(buff);
        }
    }
}

int byteToInt(char buff[]) {
    return (buff[3] << 24) | (buff[2] << 16) | (buff[1] << 8) | (buff[0]);
}
```

What  an I doing wrong?

**EDITED**:

1. Added the `read_matrix` function.
2. It seems like I'm getting a `short` instead on an `int`, since 384 = (110000000) becomes -128 = (bin) 1000000
3. Did a test, and found out that:

   char c = 128;
   int i = 0;
   i |= c;

   gives `i = -128`. Why????

Comment: please show an example of calling this, how it mat set up?

Comment: Most likely not the problem but, your error checking is weird. You write to the file before checking to see if fd is less then zero.

Comment: @FDinoff you are right about the check for successful openning... Fixing!

Comment: Show us how you wrote the "read matrix" part as well (the entire thing).

Comment: It seems like everything bigger then 384 is overflowing

Comment: It may not apply in this case, but it's safer to shift first, _THEN_ mask, to avoid sign-extension effects. It also makes the code more readable since you're always extracting the lowest byte, and a bit more compact since you don't need the additional constants.

Comment: If you're spamming raw octets in/out, I strongly advise you use `unsigned char`, not `char`, for your buffers. The last thing you need is an integer promotion from a `char` that is signed when you didn't intend it.

Comment: @keshlam I tried it, but it didn't work either. I think I found the problem, but I still can't explain/fix it. See the Edit please...

Comment: Regarding your update, `char c = 128` is already implementation-defined if `char` is 8 bits and signed. Valid values for `char` (assuming yours is signed, and I have no evidence to suggest otherwise) is `-128 .. 127`. You're overflowing your `char` data type. 128 is `0x80`, which is `-128` as a signed char if your implementation so chooses (and it did). That value is then prompted to `int` for the `i|=c` calculation and sign extended, giving you `i=-128` for your final result. I meant what I said earlier; don't use `char` for this stuff, used `unsigned char`.

Comment: don't do endian transform by hand. it's redundant:http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/endian.3.html．　and your code is extremely error prone. `int` is not necessary to be 4 byte long.

Comment: @WhozCraig +1 what the OP has is not only implementation-defined behaviour but also undefined behaviour due to left shifting of signed, negative values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your input conversion:

```
int byteToInt(char buff[]) {
    return (buff[3] << 24) | (buff[2] << 16) | (buff[1] << 8) | (buff[0]);
}
```

You don't mention which platform you are on, but on most common platforms `char` is signed. And that will cause problems. Suppose, for example, that `buff[1]` is 0x80 (0b1000000). Since it is a signed value, that is the code for the value -128. And since shift operators start by doing integer promotions on both of their arguments, that will be converted to the integer -128 before the shift operation is performed; in other words, it will have the value 0xFFFFFF80, which will become 0xFFFF8000 after the shift.

The bitwise logical operators (such as `|`) perform the usual arithmetic conversions before doing the bitwise operations; in the case of `(buff[1] << 8) | (buff[0])`, the left-hand operator will already be a signed int (because the type of `<<` is the type of its *promoted* left-hand argument); the right-hand argument, an implicitly signed `char`, will also be promoted to a signed int, so again if it were 0x80, it would end up being sign-extended to 0xFFFFFF80.

In either case, the bitwise-or operation will end up with unwanted high-order 1 bits.

Explicitly casting `buff[x]` to an `unsigned int` won't help, because it will first be sign-extended to an `int` before being reinterpreted as an `unsigned int`. Instead, it is necessary to cast it to an `unsigned char`:

```
int byteToInt(char buff[]) {
    return   ((unsigned char)buff[3] << 24)
           | ((unsigned char)buff[2] << 16)
           | ((unsigned char)buff[1] << 8)
           | (unsigned char)buff[0];
}
```

Since `int` may be 16-bit, it would be better to use `long`, and indeed it would be better to use `unsigned long` to avoid other conversion issues. That means doing a double cast:

```
unsigned long byteToInt(char buff[]) {
    return   ((unsigned long)(unsigned char)buff[3] << 24)
           | ((unsigned long)(unsigned char)buff[2] << 16)
           | ((unsigned long)(unsigned char)buff[1] << 8)
           | (unsigned long)(unsigned char)buff[0];
}
```

Comment: `(unsigned char)buff[3] << 24` is not portable.  `unsigned char` promotes to `int`.  C specifies `int` as at _least_ 16 bits.  If `int` was 16-bit, then shifting `int` 24 is undefined.  But then OP appears to be assuming (wrong) `int` is at least 32-bit.

Comment: @chux: I believe it's theoretically non-portable even if `int` is 32-bit because there is no guarantee that left shifting a positive signed int will result in the expected negative signed int (although the result is unspecified, not undefined.) But that swamp is too deep to wade in on a holiday. And do have a happy one :)

Comment: From the swampy abyss the ooze drips from a head nodding and murmuring "Yes, shift UB, muddy - very muddy" as he wanders back to his lair and pins up his stocking.  (nice hat)

Answer (score 1):

What you have is an undefined behaviour often overlooked. *Left shifting of signed negative values is undefined*. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22734721/183120) for details.

When you do this

```
int byteToInt(char buff[]) {
    return (buff[3] << 24) | (buff[2] << 16) | (buff[1] << 8) | (buff[0]);
}
```

even if one element of `buff` has a negative value (I.e. one of the binary data's value sets the MSB) then you hit undefined behaviour. Since your data is binary, reading it as `unsigned` makes the most sense. You could use a standard type which makes the signedness and length explicit, such as `uint8_t` from `stdint.h`.