# right Shift Operator infinite loop

Tags: c, bit-shift

Why this code is going into infinite loop?

While it will work on other machine. Also the machine is `little endian.
It will go on printing -1 values;

```
void printfbit(int n)
{
    while (n) {
        if (n & 1)
            printf("1");
        else
            printf("0");
        n = n >> 1;
        printf("\t %d\n",n);
    }
    //printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Closely related to [Shift operator in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7622/1708801)

Comment: endianness isn't relevant here

Answer (score 7):

From the C standard (see section 6.5.7 *Bitwise shift operators*):

> The result of **E1 >> E2** is **E1** right-shifted **E2** bit positions. If **E1** has an unsigned type
>   or if **E1** has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral
>   part of the quotient of **E1 / 2<sup>E2</sup>**. ***If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the
>   resulting value is implementation-defined.***

The behavior you're seeing with an infinite loop is due to the right-shift semantics of that particular implementation being: right-shifting a signed integer preserves the sign bit.

Hence, for any negative input you'll eventually end up with `0xffffffff...` (== -1), and the condition for continuing your loop will always be fulfilled.

An example:

Original input:      `0x80000000`
After one shift:     `0xC0000000`
After two shifts:   `0xE0000000`
After three shifts: `0xF0000000`
After four shifts:   `0xF8000000`
etc

Comment: could you please tell us how it works for other machines?

Comment: On _what_ other machine? And for which compiler?

Comment: i was just extending the question from OP.

Comment: This works the same for all machines that use the two's complent method for representing negative numbes (that is, the left-most bit indicates the sign of number).

Comment: This is implementation defined behavior see the link in my comment to the question. Preserving the sign bit is one possible behavior but it is not required behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Right-shifting signed integer will preserve sign bit. That's the rule applied here, leading to the above mentioned behaviour