# why does bitwise shift replace date with 1s instead of 0 here?

Tags: c++, bitmask

For a program utilising bitmasks I desired to write numbers in binary... i.e To copy the first 8 bits of `x` to `z`, I write

```
y = 0xff000000;
z = 0;
z = (y & x) | z
```

Where `x, y, z` are all `int`. Now using *left shift* and *right shift* operators I wanted to move 1s of `y` right or left to bitmask another set of bits, so I write the following code

```
cout<< bitset<32>(y>>10) <<"\n" << bitset<32>(y<<10) <<endl;
```

Now what I expected as output was:

```
00000000001111111100000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
```

but I got:

```
11111111111111111100000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
```

1. Why are the new bits '1' intead of '0' on first line of output?
2. How can I change current output to desired output?

Comment: use unsigned numbers

Comment: what if i have to use a negative number ?

Comment: Then you need to decide explicitly how you want to handle the negative case. If you require a *logical* shift operation, you'll need to enforce it since your C compiler is likely using *arithmetic* shift for `<<` and `>>` as discussed in [Shift operator in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622/shift-operator-in-c). You'd replace `y >> 10` with something like `((unsigned)y) >> 10` (or `unsigned long` or whatever unsigned type you need) if you want to retain the sign bit in the shift, as an example. Based upon your treatment of `y`, it's unclear why it's a signed value.

Comment: Then you shouldn't hack the bits of negative numbers. Hacking bits of negative numbers is as bad/ugly/dangerous/nonportable/UB as hacking the bits of a float.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

y is a signed integer. In signed integers, the topmost bit is the sign bit, and when you right-shift signed integers the topmost bit propagates.

Using eight-bit values: -4 is

```
11111100
```

What do you think makes sense, when you right shift -4?

Do you expect to get -2:

```
11111110
```

Or do you expect to get 126?

```
01111110
```

Remember that a left shift is an equivalent to multiplying by 2, so a right shift is equivalent to dividing by 2 (and discarding the remainder).

If you want to shift a signed integer, and get unsigned integer semantics, cast it to an unsigned integer, first.

Comment: The effect of right-shifting a negative value is implementation defined. It's not required to propagate the topmost bit.

Comment: +1 for the explanation. Per @PeteBecker comment, here's an SO reference discussing it: [Shift operator in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622/shift-operator-in-c). In this particular case, the OP's tools *happen to use* arithmetic shift.

Comment: I'd be curious to know whether any modern platform implements >> on signed values as a logical shift.

Comment: I agree. The referenced Wikipedia article suggests that it is *usually* implemented as arithmetic. I think it's important to note as a small caveat that it's *possible* a given C compiler may use logical per the standard.