# why am i getting -256 after doing leftshift?

Tags: c, bit-shift

I am not able to understand the output of below code . It gives me output as **-256**.

```
char c = 0xFF;
printf("%d\n",c<<8);
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: By the way, `(char)0xff` is an odd way to write `(char)-1`.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/cpp/cpp/left-shift-and-right-shift-operators-input-and-output)?

Comment: Actually, your whole code is an odd way to calculate (-1) * 256

Comment: @spectras AFAIK, the C standard leaves it explicitly open, whether a platform uses `char` `signed` or `unsigned`. Thus, `(char)-1` is as good or as bad as `(char)0xff`. The system library functions uses often `int` instead of `char` in the respective cases. (For me, this is one possibility to handle a `char` independent of `signed`/`unsigned`.)

Comment: @Scheff> true (it can even be changed with a compiler flag on most compiler). It was in his specific case, hinting at what was happening.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in your platform `char` is a signed type, which goes from `-128` to `127`. Following the `2's complement representation`, positive numbers are represented from `0x00` to `0x7f` and from there, the negative numbers start. So `0x80` is -128, `0x81` is `-127`, and so on, until arriving to `0xFF` which is `-1`.

In your code, you are assigning `-1` to the variable `c`. When you bitshift a `char`, it gets promoted to `int`, so you end up with the representation of `-1` in integer, which is (just to give an example) `0xFFFFFFFF` if `int` was 32 bits.

When you bitshift a negative number to the left, the least significant bits get filled by 0's, so you end up having `0xFFFFFF00` which is `-256`.

Comment: Incidentally, the same output would be achieved on a silent-wraparound two's-complement implementation where `int` is 16 bits and `char` is any allowable size,

Answer (score 0):

Computers represent negative numbers by using [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). When you declare a `char`, you allocate a byte which is 8 bits. If the variable is signed and its most significant bit is 1, it will be the negative value of the `2^n` place.

For example, a `char` which has 8 bits and its sigbit is 1, `0x80 = 1000 0000 = -2^8 = -128`. When you set the remaining bits to 1, you add back the positive values of each `2^n` bit place. See more about binary representation of numbers [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Binary_arithmetic). Each hexadecimal character represent four bits, in the case of `0xFF`, you set `c`'s eight bits to 1s.

```
char c = 0xFF; // 0xFF = 1111 1111 = -1
```

So you have `-128 + 64 + 32 + 16 + 8 + 4 + 2 + 1 = -1`

When you preform a left-shift `c << x`, you move `c`'s bits to the left `x` amount while padding the right with zeros as you shift. Here is a explanation from a previous stackoverflow answer by @legends2k.

> The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1×2E2, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. If E1 has a signed type and non-negative value, and E1×2E2 is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behaviour is undefined. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622/are-the-shift-operators-arithmetic-or-logical-in-c)

In addition, when you preform a shift, you promote `c` to an `int`.

> **ISO/IEC 9899:2011 (C)**
>
> [§6.5.7](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.5.7.html) Bitwise shift operators
>
> 1183 The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands.

To preserve the value of -1 being `0xFF` in the sense of a `char`, on a 32-bit machine, an integer is 4 bytes with its bits all being 1s to represent -1 or `0xFFFFFFFF`.

When you shift 8 bits to the left, `(0xFFFFFFFF << 8) = 0xFFFFFF00 = -256`

Comment: there is a big difference between *complement* and *compliment* :)