# Is there a way of using bitwise operator to combine digit bits?

Tags: c

For example, I have two digit bits:

```
0b0111111
0b0000110
```

I want to shift a state variable by 7 digits and combine them together.

```
0b00001100111111
```

Can I accomplish by shifting?

Comment: Yes. What have you tried?

Comment: If you have to variables `x` and `y` with those values: `(y << 7) | x`

Comment: Are you really using C? Base-2 literals are only supported in C++14, not C11.

Comment: @Dai Using xCode on Mac (not sure the exact compiler, I want to say GCC off the top of my head) allows for binary literals.

Comment: @MatthewKerian Try it with `-pedantic`

Comment: @user3386109 Why does that matter though? If binary liteterals work why would I want to make them not work?

Comment: @MatthewKerian Binary literals aren't technically part of the language. Which means that if you want your code to be portable, you can't use them. That's the purpose of `-pedantic`. It helps you write code that complies with the standard, and therefore has a better chance of porting correctly.

Comment: @user3386109 Ahh, thank you. I didn't realize that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do this by shifting the bottom number left 7 digits, then performing a bitwise OR of the result and the first number.

```
unsigned int a = 0x3f;
unsigned int b = 0x06;
unsigned int result = (b << 7) | a;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned char a = 0b00000110;
unsigned char b = 0b01111111;
unsigned short c = (b << 8); // shift everything left 8 bits to set the high bits
c &= 0xFF00; // clear out the lower bits - not necessary in C
c |= a; // set the lower 8 bits
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned int X = 0b00111111;
unsigned int Y = 0b00000110;

unsigned int Z = ((X << 7) & 0xFF00) | Y;
```

Comment: This one fails, absolutely.

Comment: `0xFF00` is not the right mask for a 7-bit value that's been shifted by 7 bits. Not to mention that `Y` is the one that's supposed to get shifted.

Comment: Correct.   Someone submitted that answer when I stepped away from my workstation for a few minutes.  I think it was my evil twin brother.

Answer (score -1):

```
int a = 0b0111111;
int b = 0b0000110;

int combined = (a << 7) | b;
```

Comment: I would not use signed ints either

Comment: When shifting left, there is no difference between arithmetic and logical shift. When shifting right, the type of shift depends on the type of the value being shifted. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622/are-the-shift-operators-arithmetic-or-logical-in-c#7632