# problem in understanding decimal to binary function with bitwise operators in c++

Tags: c++, function, bitwise-operators

How this function change decimal to binary?
I know what bitwise operation do but I can't understand what this function do in work

```
    void function(int a){
        if(a){
            function(a>>1);
            cout<<(a&1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: For negative a, the value of a >> 1 is implementation-defined.

Comment: You need to google a few things. "Left and right shift", "Bitwise AND and OR" and "Recursion".

Comment: You need to target what you do not understand in this function: The bitwise operations (`<<` and `&`)? The recursion of `function`? Something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Step 1: You call a function defined as `void function(int a)`
// which accepts one parameter of type int and returns a void.
void function(int a)
{
    // Step 2: This function checks if a is zero or some other value. 
    // If it is zero, nothing happens and the function returns.
    // If it is non-zero, we proceed inside the if block.
    if(a){
        // Step 3: we do two things here.
        // First we right-shift whatever value is stored in a.
        // Right-shifting means if we have e.g. a=8, which is 1000 in binary,
        // then rightshifting 8 would be 0100 or 4. Basically it is division by 2.
        // This continues until we have 0000.

        // Secondly, this function will call itself then. This is called recursion.
        // So the "void function(4)-> void function(2) -> void function(1)" calls will run.
        function(a>>1);

        // Here we will bitwise AND with 1.
        // So, 0001 & 0001 = 1
        // 0010 & 0001 = 0
        // 0100 & 0001 = 0
        // 1000 & 0001 = 0
        // And this is what you will see on the terminal as output: 1000
        // The 1 gets printed first, because the inner most call in the recursion
        // finishes first and the call stack unwraps back up.
        cout<<(a&1);
    }
}
```

Comment: *'First we right-shift'* - that's perhaps ambivalent; if had to rewrite the function solely based on this explanation, I'd do `a >>= 1; f(a); std::cout << (a&1)`.

Comment: @OP, To avoid the problems, mentioned for the case of negative numbers, I would change `if(a)` by `if (a>0)`.

Comment: @Aconcagua, Are you referring to "6.2.2 Evaluation Order [expr.evaluation]"? I always thought that the operation would be performed first, before the function call continues. Is it not so? If not, then apparently, I have learned something new today.

Comment: Your understanding is fine, the point is: your wording could be misunderstood. Sure the value first is shifted right, *then* passed to the function - to be more precise: *the result* of the shift is passed - wheras the operand `a` remains unchanged. *'First we right-shift'* I'd understand, in contrast to, as modifying the operand as well, just as in `f(a >>= 1)` (note the additional `=`).

Comment: Apart from: It is totally legal to right-shift 0 (no UB at all)! `0 >> 1` just remains 0...

Comment: Thank you. Edited as suggested. Indeed. I was confusing myself with the negative numbers again, which some people had pointed out, but in a different context.

Answer (score 3):

Recursive function

```
void function(int a){
    if(a){                 // if a is not 0, continue calling recursively
        function(a>>1);    // right shift a one step i.e. divide by 2, then call ourselves
        cout<<(a&1);       // bitwise & with a i.e print if a is odd or even.
    }
}
```

Example

```
function(4);
a = 4, a>>1 == 2
function(2);
a = 2, a>>1 == 0
function(0); will end recursion
cout << (2&1) will print 0 since 0x10 & 0x01 == 0x00
cout << (4&1) will print 0 since 0x20 & 0x01 == 0x00
```

Answer (score 3):

```
void function(int a)    // function declaration
{
    if(a)               // a != 0?
    {
        function(a>>1); // recursive call to function with a shifted right one bit
        cout<<(a&1);    // print out least significant bit of a
    }
}
```

This function prints out a binary representation of a number given, e. g. a initially 13:

```
f(13)            // 13 == 0b1101
{
    f(6)         // 0b1101 >> 1 == 0b0110
    {
        f(3)     // 0b0110 >> 1 == 0b0011
        {
            f(1) // etc
            {
                f(0)
                { }  // does nothing
                std::cout << (1 & 1); // 1, most significant bit of original 13
            }
            std::cout << (3 & 1);     // 1
        }
        std::cout << (6 & 1);         // 0
    }
    std::cout << (13 & 1);            // 1
}

1101 in total
```

Signature is dangerous, though; wheras it is implementation defined if the shift is logic (always 0 shifted in at the left) or arithmetic (shift in current sign bit again), [*usually*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622/are-the-shift-operators-arithmetic-or-logical-in-c) (question is C, but applies for C++ as well) arithmetic shift is implemented for signed values.

So you would end up in an endless recursion if you pass a negative value to the function. Better:

```
void function(unsigned int a);
//            ^^^^^^^^
```

For *unsigned* values, logic and arithmetic shift are the same...

Side note: if you pass 0 initially to the function, you don't get any output at all (either variant).