# Left shift operator in C giving strange result

Tags: c, bit-shift

I have the following program:

```
int main()
{
    int64_t a = 241294423792285589;
    printf("a = %lld, a << 63 = %lld", a, a << 63);
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting `a << 63` to be 0, but it prints out:

```
a = 241294423792285589, a << 63 = -9223372036854775808
```

Why is this?

Comment: maybe check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622/are-the-shift-operators-arithmetic-or-logical-in-c

Comment: Could you explain why you expect that `a << 63` should be 0?

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to bitwise shift signed values. It can give undefined or implementation-defined results. With unsigned values the shifts act more predictably.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you convert these integers to signed 2's complement binary you can see why:

241294423792285589 in binary is

```
0000001101011001010000000000000000000000011010111111011110010101
```

Shifting this left by 63 spots will result in the right-most `1` ending up in the left-most binary digit:

```
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Which in 2's complement binary is -9223372036854775808.

You can find binary <-> decimal converters online (such as this one: https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-binary.html) that can help make this more clear.

Or you can even try this bitshift calculator: https://bit-calculator.com/bit-shift-calculator

Answer (score 4):

Your shift expression has undefined behavior. There's no value you can meaningfully expect from that shift.

In C behavior of left shift `E1 << E2` for signed `E1` is described by 6.5.7/4

> If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup> is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you left shift an odd number (a number with the least signifiant bit set) 63 places to the left in a 64 bit word.  The value you obtain is

```
0b1000_0000_0000_0000_...._0000
```

or

```
0x8000000000000000
```

that (in two's complement) is the number you post in your question.

Anyway, shifting 63 places a **signed 64bit number** is undefined behaviour, so that means that you can receive anything at all... event that huge negative number.