# Why is /=2 different from >>=1 for signed integers, and compiles to different asm?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, integer-division

```
unsigned int a=200;
//mov   dword ptr [a],0C8h  
a >>= 1;
//mov   eax,dword ptr [a]  
//shr   eax,1  
//mov   dword ptr [a],eax  
a /= 2;
//mov   eax,dword ptr [a]  
//shr   eax,1  
//mov   dword ptr [a],eax  
int b = -200;
//mov   dword ptr [b],0FFFFFF38h  
b /= 2;
//mov   eax,dword ptr [b]  
//cdq  
//sub   eax,edx  
//sar   eax,1  
//mov   dword ptr [b],eax  
b >>= 1;
//mov   eax,dword ptr [b]  
//sar   eax,1  
//mov   dword ptr [b],eax
```

im using msvc, // is the assembly for that C statement.

Why is signed int `/=2` is different from `>>=1`?  What are `cdq` and `sub` doing?  Are they necessary?

Comment: C says they round differently for negative numbers (toward 0 vs. toward -Inf); the asm has to reflect that.

Comment: Because `-7 / 2 = -3` but with `>> 1` you will get `-4`

Comment: all of you, thanks a lot. i under stand why are they differ-.

Comment: Arithmetic right shift vs logical right shift.  some ISAs have a real or pseudo ASR instruction to handle this some dont and you have to synthesize it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622/are-the-shift-operators-arithmetic-or-logical-in-c   implementation-defined (I didnt check a current spec) as to whether the C compiler is arithmetic or logical so that same code on certain compilers and/or with certain command line options may produce the same results for divide and shift.  implementation defined.

Comment: The result of E1 >> E2 is E1 right-shifted E2 bit positions. If E1 has an unsigned type
or if E1 has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of E1 / 2 E2 . If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined.

Comment: a draft from 2007.  so dont assume that a signed right shift is arithmetic...use divide and let the compiler optimize it into an arithmetic shift.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dividing a negative integer by 2 is not the same as shifting it to the right by 1.
For example

```
-7 / 2 = -3
```

With shifts:

```
11111001b >> 1 = 11111100b which is -4
```

Thus the compiler has to take care of the case when the integer is negative

> What are cdq and sub doing? Are they necessary?

`cdq` performs the following EDX:EAX ← sign-extend of EAX.

Thus if the value in EAX is negative, EDX will get 0xFFFFFFFF (which is -1), otherwise it will be 0 (due to the sign extension of EAX).

```
sub eax, edx ; will either result in 'eax - 0' (if EAX is positive) or
             ;                       'eax - (-1)' (if EAX is negative)
```

Which in case of the above example will normalize the -7 to `-7 - (-1) = -6` and then `-6 >> 1 = -3`.

Comment: @sunkue, I added explanation for the `cdq`.

Answer (score 1):

Arithmetic shift right is actually the divide by 2 but is rounded to the nearest smaller integer. so `-7 >> 1` is `-4`

Mathematical divide (as required by C standard) by two is rounded to the nearest absolute integer instead (ie towards zero).

The code is compiling to another sets of instreuctions:

```
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR x
        mov     eax, edx
        shr     eax, 31
        add     eax, edx
        sar     eax
        mov     DWORD PTR x, eax
```

https://godbolt.org/z/No6u6V

Comment: Divide by 2 of an odd number is exactly half way between two integers.  The question is which one it picks, out of the two equidistant choices.  C99 requires it to pick truncation toward 0 (unlike arithmetic right shift, which is like division by 2 with rounding toward -Inf.)

Comment: @PeterCordes It is what I wrote. Now I made it clearer

Comment: I'm not familiar with "nearest absolute integer" meaning towards zero.  Is that terminology standard?  A google search for `nearest absolute integer` doesn't turn up anything that would indicate it means towards zero.  So yes, good edit, it needed that clarification.

Comment: Note that "towards zero" is a C99 and later requirement and OP has "im using msvc" which is not C99 compliant.  With C89, `/2` and `>>1` may be the same.