# Concatenate 2 16 bit words into one 16 bit word in c

Tags: c, concatenation, bit-shift

I am trying to get the Least significant 4 bits of one word and the most significant 12 bits of another word and concatenate them into a single word. I am working in C, which I haven't worked with much in the past.

```
int a;
int b;
int c;
int a_masked;
int b_masked;
a = 0x1234;
b = 0xABCD;

a_masked = a & 0X000F;
b_masked = b & 0xFFF0;

c = ((a_masked << 12) || b_masked >> 4);

printf("%d", c);
```

C should be 4ABC, but my result is 1.

Comment: Note: `%x` and `%X` will print an `int` in hexadecimal, which will make it easier to see if your bitwise operation succeeded.

Comment: Apart from the `||`, watch it when shifting _signed_ values (i.e. probably don't do that): https://stackoverflow.com/q/7622/6372809

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`||` operator, which you used, is a *logical* OR operator and it returns 0 or 1.

You should use a *bitwise* OR operator `|` (one vertical line, not two).